# Best practice for ordering a collection of key/value pairs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, collections

what would be an efficient (and userfriendly) way to realize the following in javascript/jQuery?

Depeding on the mime-type of a file, a callback should be executed. The callback is defined by the developer by providing a mime-type description with optional wildcards (e.g. text/javascript, text/**, **/*) and the callback itself. There must be a specified order in which the declared types are matched against the given mime-type of the file. For example must text/plain have a higher priority than text/*.

Here some ideas:

**Using a simple object**

```
var handler = {
 'text/javascript' : callback0,
 'text/*' : callback1
}
```

This **would** be the most intuitive solution, but the ordering is **not guaranteed**.

**Maintain two lists**

```
var order = ['text/javascript', 'text/*'];
var handler = [callback0, callback1];
```

This is would be hard to maintain if there are more than two or three types and you are using anonymous functions as callbacks.

**Adding an index by wrapping the callback into an object**

```
var handler = {
  'text/javascript' : {index: 0, callback0},
  'text/*' : {index: 1, callback1}
};
```

... change thousands of index-properties when inserting an item at the beginning.

**Using an array of arrays**

```
var handler = [
  ['text/javascript', callback0],
  ['text/*', callback1]
];
```

This might me more userfriendly than the others, but there is no direct access for known mime-types without iterating over the elements (this would be nice-to-have).

So there are some ways to do the thing I want, but what would be the *right* way (and why)? Maybe someone has a pattern?

Best,
Hacksteak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the 'simple object' solution AND the order array form the 'maintain two lists' solution.

Iterate through the order array with a block of code that uses the `handler` simple object to do something that either breaks the loop or continues to the next loop iteration.

EDIT TO RESPOND TO A COMMENT

I agree with your comment.  I would do something like this to make it just one variable:

```
var handlers = {
  handler: {
    'text/javascript': callback0,
    'text/*': callback1
  },
  order: ["text/javascript", "text/*"]
};
```

Although I would pick better names for the `handlers` variable and/or the `handlers.handler` property.

ANOTHER RESPONSE TO ANOTHER COMMENT

Maybe you should just modify `handlers.handler` and `handlers.order` one-mime-type-at-a-time:

```
var handlers = { handler: {}, order: [] }; // initialize as empty

// add 'text/javascript' mime type
handlers['text/javascript'] = callback0;
handlers.order.push('text/javascript');

// add 'text/*' mime type
handlers['text/*'] = callback1;
handlers.order.push('text/*');
```

That method fills a little repetitive, but should be easy to maintain in the future.  If you want, you can write a function that adds a new property to `handlers.handler` and appends a new mime-type to `handlers.order`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The combination you mentioned offers direct access and keeps the ordering. The only thing I don't like is the redundancy of the types. IMHO this is a potiential point of error when changing something.

Comment: After your edit there is still the redundancy of the mime-types. In general I think it must be absolutly avoided. That is my very personal opinion. In the past years I worked on projects where redundancy seemed to part of the conceptual design. It is horrible to maintain. Don't want to think about situations where a third developer should refactor and splits up the two definitions to different places.

Comment: I don't understand.  I used the sample mime-types from your original question.

Comment: If you introduce a new type (e.g. image/svg) you have to write it twice (to the 'handler' and the 'order' var). There are some risks in doing so. One is just to forget one of the two entries. Furthermore, someone might change image/svg to image/jpeg. That change has to be done at both vars. That might seem trivial but in practice those kind of error may cost much time and money to find. As I said in my first comment, your code will work great, but I don't like the way how it is done (please don't hate me ;) ).

Comment: Finaly I decided to do it with your solution in the background. The developer has to define an array as mentioned under "Using an array of arrays" in my question. IMHO this is the most friendly syntax, avoiding any redundant information. Internaly this array is transformed to the structure you described.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ordering on objects is in insertion order on most vendors, except for V8 which is true except for numerical indices. See the references below.

I probably wouldn't be doing any looping. I would probably do something like this:

```
var handler = {
    text: {
        javascript: callback0,
        '*': callback1
    },
    '*' : {
        '*': callback3
    }
};
var mime = 'whatevs/whatevs'.split('/');
var callback = handler[mime[0]][mime[1]] || handler['*']['*'];
callback();
```

### References

1. [Iterating JavaScript object properties and arrays with for..in when ordering is important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122548/iterating-javascript-object-properties-and-arrays-with-for-in-when-ordering-is-i)
2. http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

Comment: I did not think about a tree like structure but it seems to be good approach (even if this questions title would not fit anymore ^^).

Comment: Hmm, the tree structure seems to me less flexible than a list. XML types (e.g. image/svg+xml) are not easy to address in a tree. You can add two childs (svg and svg+xml) or introduce an optional second child level. At the moment I don't know if I need to take care about it or just strip it... need some time for thinking :)

Comment: But, I do believe that I answered your question in the first part, I just added extra. :-)