# What is the correct Ordering of this Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript

In Firefox the output is ordered Alphabetically (which is the order they are declared). In IE and Chrome they are numerical. All latest versions.

Which is correct?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeArray()
{
    var array = [{5:'Five',4:'Four',1:'One',3:'Three',2:'Two'}];
    var msg = '';

    for (var val in array[0])
    {
        msg = msg + val;
    }   
    alert(msg);
}
</script>
<input type="button" onClick="makeArray();" value="Press Me" />
</body>
</html>
```

Back Story...
In [SpiraTeam](http://www.inflectra.com/SpiraTeam/) (Our current bug tracking system) many of the lists (users, modules, etc) are ordered using a similar format to the above. This makes finding stuff very hard and annoying unless you use FireFox. My interest is purely academical, I only ask because I want to know which browser's correct.

Comment: There's actually only one item in the array - and object with 5 properties. So I think the correct way to phrase the question is "what is the correct ordering of properties in an object?"

Comment: You can find more info about order of iteration in a object here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop/280861#280861

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you are asking: ***what is the order of properties within object literal when iterating using `for` loop?*** The array is irrelevant here.

And the answer is: **it is unspecified**. Most of the time it will be the same as you see in the code, but there is no guarantee.

This question has been asked hundreds of times:

- [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713)
- [How to iterate javascript object properties in the order they were written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647201)
- [Iteration order of for..in loops in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976054)
- [Chrome and probably Opera sort object properties automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886314)
- [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795)

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know what to search for - I'm not a web developer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be that you are not iterating over an Array, but an Object...

[ECMA](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.6.4) doesn't seem to define in step 5 how to go about this... (alphabetically, numerically etc)

Comment: It's not me who's doing it - that's just the code for the bug tracker I am stuck with.