# How to access the first property of a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object

Is there an elegant way to access the first property of an object...

1. where you don't know the name of your properties
2. without using a loop like `for .. in` or jQuery's `$.each`

For example, I need to access `foo1` object without knowing the name of foo1:

```
var example = {
    foo1: { /* stuff1 */},
    foo2: { /* stuff2 */},
    foo3: { /* stuff3 */}
};
```

Comment: it's probably better to transform it into an Array first

Answer (score 1916, accepted):

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal' };
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]; //returns 'someVal'

Object.values(obj)[0]; // returns 'someVal'
```

Using this you can access also other properties by indexes. Be aware tho! `Object.keys` or `Object.values` return order is not guaranteed as per ECMAScript however unofficially it is by all major browsers implementations, please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202095 for details on this.

Comment: You say that it's not the fastest way. What way would be faster?

Comment: This is not very efficient as it creates an entire array of all of the object's keys.

Comment: @T Nguyen I would post it if i knew it :)

Comment: This works PERFECT for me as I am trying to use both 'keys' on the same string ... element.append('<option value=' + Object.keys(data[i])[0] + '>' + Object.keys(data[i])[1] + '</option>');
THIS should be the answer!

Comment: This works for the example, but I think the order of keys isn't entirely well defined. That might be a gotcha for some code.

Comment: `for(var i in obj){ console.log(i); break; }` is two times faster that above code, as seen at [http://jsben.ch/#/AUPq5](http://jsben.ch/#/AUPq5)

Comment: @DavChana - You had your benchmark set up wrong. The *boilerplate block* will always be executed and your *block 2* was empty, meaning the first result represents execution *boilerplate+block1*, and the second result represents only *boilerplate*. __Here is the correct benchmark: [http://jsben.ch/#/R9aLQ](http://jsben.ch/#/R9aLQ)__, showing they are pretty much equal (run the test multiple times).

Comment: I wish `first()` or something similar could handle this.

Comment: As others have said, not ideal for every case but great for a simple one-liner. To avoid a speed hit you can cache the key array before loops, etc. `var k = Object.keys(obj); for(...){foo = obj[k[i]];}`. Then again that's just a clunky way of using `for...in`.

Comment: This is returning the value and he is asking for the first key name in the object.

Comment: Shameless plug for shorter version https://stackoverflow.com/a/42450925/3599414

Comment: this solved my challenge perfectly

Answer (score 159):

Try the [`for … in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in) and break after the first iteration:

```
for (var prop in object) {
    // object[prop]
    break;
}
```

Comment: I think this is about the only option. I'm not sure you're guaranteed that the properties will be iterated in a predictable/useful order though. I.e., you may intend foo1 but get foo3.  
If the properties are numbered as in the example, you could do a string compare to ascertain the identifier ending in '1'. Then again, if ordinality is the main concern of the collection, you should probably use an array instead of an object.

Comment: If anyone else is concerned about the order, most browsers behave predictably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop

Comment: var prop;
for (prop in object) break;
//object[prop]

Comment: Old answer but. You might want to check if the property belongs to the object. like: for(..){ if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue; .... break; } just in case the object is actually empty it does not traverses the prototype or something.

Answer (score 152):

You can also do `Object.values(example)[0]`.

Comment: This is not available in all browsers, referencing https://stackoverflow.com/a/38748490/719689

Comment: Update from 2019, I think that this works on most browsers except for IE
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Comment: @theUtherSide the ***ordering*** is the same for all `Object.keys`, `Object.values` and `for...in`, only significant difference is that `for...in` loops also on prototype chain therefore you have to check manually for `hasOwnProperty()` there.

Answer (score 58):

You can use **Object.values()** to access values of an object:

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal' };
Object.values(obj)[0]; // someVal
```

Comment: Simplest and easiest way of doing this

Answer (score 56):

Use `Object.keys` to get an array of the properties on an object. Example:

```
var example = {
    foo1: { /* stuff1 */},
    foo2: { /* stuff2 */},
    foo3: { /* stuff3 */}
};

var keys = Object.keys(example); // => ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"] (Note: the order here is not reliable)
```

Documentation and cross-browser shim provided [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). An example of its use can be found in another one of my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538265/777929).

**Edit**: for clarity, I just want to echo what was correctly stated in other answers: the key order in JavaScript objects is undefined.

Answer (score 27):

A one-liner version:

```
var val = example[function() { for (var k in example) return k }()];
```

Comment: Sometimes it can be risky to use `for in` without checking `hasOwnProperty` as the object contain other unwanted values appended to it programmatically so you could end up getting an unwanted result from this snippet. Just because its short and neat doesn't mean its safe optimal.

Answer (score 26):

There isn't a "first" property. Object keys are unordered.

If you loop over them with for `(var foo in bar)` you will get them in **some** order, but it may change in future (especially if you add or remove other keys).

Comment: Awesome. I've been using an object to implement a map that maintains insertion order. That breaks once I remove a value because the next insertion fills in the gap. :(

Comment: key / value order should preserved in newer versions of JS

Answer (score 16):

Here is a cleaner way of getting the first key:

```js
var object = {
    foo1: 'value of the first property "foo1"',
    foo2: { /* stuff2 */},
    foo3: { /* stuff3 */}
};

let [firstKey] = Object.keys(object)

console.log(firstKey)
console.log(object[firstKey])
```

Comment: But why the array around `[first]`. User did not request an array as the answer.  Why do this over `first = Object.keys(example)[0]` which will do the same without needing to wrap the answer in an array.  Why is yours cleaner please?

Comment: That is a destructuring assignment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 15):

The top answer could generate the whole array and then capture from the list. Here is an another effective shortcut

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal' };
Object.entries(obj)[0][1] // someVal
```

Answer (score 12):

Solution with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) library:

```
_.find(example) // => {name: "foo1"}
```

but there is no guarantee of the object properties internal storage order because it depends on javascript VM implementation.

Comment: Just tested this, and it doesn't work. It returns the value only, not the key/value pair.

Comment: There is no mention in the question that it should return the key/value pair, he just asks for the object and the accepted answer does just as much as this lodash function: it returns the content of the first property.
It might not suit your specific needs, but this answer IS correct based on the original question.

Comment: Yes does the job, useful when you know your object will have only one child object `var object = { childIndex: { .. } }; var childObject = _.find(Object);`

Answer (score 9):

To get the first key name in the object you can use:

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal' };
Object.keys(obj)[0]; //returns 'first'
```

Returns a string, so you cant access nested objects if there were, like:

`var obj = { first: { someVal : { id : 1} };` Here with that solution you can't access id.

The best solution if you want to get the actual object is using lodash like:

```
obj[_.first(_.keys(obj))].id
```

To return the value of the first key, (if you don't know exactly the first key name):

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal' };
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]; //returns 'someVal'
```

if you know the key name just use:

```
obj.first
```

or

```
obj['first']
```

Answer (score 9):

if someone prefers array destructuring

```
const [firstKey] = Object.keys(object);
```

Answer (score 8):

No. An object literal, as defined by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#object_literals) is:

> a list of zero or more pairs of property names and associated values of an object, enclosed in curly braces ({}).

Therefore an object literal is not an array, and you can only access the properties using their explicit name or a `for` loop using the `in` keyword.

Comment: For others only seeing the green tick on this answer, there is another solution further down the page with currently 350 upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

This has been covered here before.

The concept of first does not apply to object properties, and the order of a for...in loop is not guaranteed by the specs, however in practice  it is reliably FIFO *except* critically for chrome ([bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=883)). Make your decisions accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend you to use Object.keys since its not supported in old IE versions. But if you really need that, you could use the code above to guarantee the back compatibility:

```
if (!Object.keys) {
Object.keys = (function () {
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
    hasDontEnumBug = !({toString: null}).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
    dontEnums = [
      'toString',
      'toLocaleString',
      'valueOf',
      'hasOwnProperty',
      'isPrototypeOf',
      'propertyIsEnumerable',
      'constructor'
    ],
    dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

return function (obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' && typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null) throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');

  var result = [];

  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) result.push(prop);
  }

  if (hasDontEnumBug) {
    for (var i=0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
      if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) result.push(dontEnums[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}})()};
```

Feature     Firefox (Gecko)4 (2.0)   Chrome 5  Internet Explorer 9  Opera 12    Safari 5

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

But if you only need the first one, we could arrange a shorter solution like:

```
var data = {"key1":"123","key2":"456"};
var first = {};
for(key in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        first.key = key;
        first.content =  data[key];
        break;
    }
}
console.log(first); // {key:"key",content:"123"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access "the first property of an object", it might mean that there is something wrong with your logic. The order of an object's properties should not matter.

Comment: You're right. I don't need the first one, per se, but just one of the foo properties so I can work with it.  I only need one and wasn't sure if there was a way just to grab the "first" one without using for ... in.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way to do this, without calling `Object.keys()` or `Object.values()` which returns an array:

```
Object.prototype.firstKey = function () {
  for (const k in this) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, k)) return k;
  }
  return null;
};
```

Then you can use it like:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(obj.firstKey()) //=> 'a'
```

This doesn't necessarily return the first key, see [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)

Answer (score 0):

we can also do with this approch.

```
var example = {
  foo1: { /* stuff1 */},
  foo2: { /* stuff2 */},
  foo3: { /* stuff3 */}
}; 
Object.entries(example)[0][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but most of the solutions assume that we know the attribute's name which it is not the case for example if you are trying to visualize data from files that the user can upload or similar cases.

This is a simple function that I use and works in both cases that you know the variable and if not it will return the first attribute of the object (sorted alphabetically)

The `label` function receives an object `d` and extract the `key` if exits, otherwise returns the first attribute of the object.

```js
const data = [
  { label: "A", value: 10 },
  { label: "B", value: 15 },
  { label: "C", value: 20 },
  { label: "D", value: 25 },
  { label: "E", value: 30 }
]

const keys = ['label', 0, '', null, undefined]

const label = (d, k) => k ? d[k] : Object.values(d)[0]

data.forEach(d => {
  console.log(`first: ${label(d)}, label: ${label(d, keys[0])}`)
})

keys.forEach(k => {
  console.log(`label of ${k}: ${label(data[0], k)}`)
})
```

For values like `0`, `''`, `null`, and `undefined` will return the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
  const dataToSend = {email:'king@gmail.com',password:'12345'};
   const formData = new FormData();
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(dataToSend).length; i++) {
     formData.append(Object.keys(dataToSend)[i], 
         Object.values(dataToSend)[i]);
      }

  console.log(formData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Any reason not to do this?

```
> example.map(x => x.name);

(3) ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"]
```

Comment: Because `.map()` only exists for [built-in iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables)

Answer (score -1):

Basic syntax to iterate through key-value gracefully

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

// expected output:
// "a: somestring"
// "b: 42"
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Answer (score -4):

As others have pointed out, if the order of properties is important, storing them in an object is not a good idea. Instead, you should use an array via square brackets. E.g.,

```
var example = [ {/* stuff1 */}, { /* stuff2 */}, { /* stuff3 */}];
var first = example[0];
```

Note that you lose the 'foo' identifiers. But you could add a name property to the contained objects:

```
var example = [ 
  {name: 'foo1', /* stuff1 */},
  {name: 'foo2', /* stuff2 */},
  {name: 'foo3', /* stuff3 */}
];
var whatWasFirst = example[0].name;
```

For those seeking an answer to a similar question, namely: "How do I find one or more properties that match a certain pattern?", I'd recommend using `Object.keys()`. To extend benekastah's answer:

```
for (const propName of Object.keys(example)) {
  if (propName.startsWith('foo')) {
    console.log(`Found propName ${propName} with value ${example[propName]}`);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: there are situations in which we can't. We're assuming we can't change the fact that they're not in an array

Comment: I think it's useful to push back on the design a bit for readers who can control their JSON schema. Essentially, I'm extending Flavius Stef's answer with some examples.