# How to get first member of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access the first property of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/access-the-first-property-of-an-object)

I have a javascript object like this:

```
var list = {
    item1: "a",
    item2: "b",
    item3: "c",
    item4: "d"
};
```

Using reflection in JS, I can say list["item1"] to get or set each member programmatically, but I don't want to rely on the name of the member (object may be extended). So **I want to get the first member of this object**.

If I write the following code it returns undefined. Anybody knows how this can be done?

```
var first = list[0]; // this returns undefined
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Comment: But what if you change the code that initialises that object. Surely it's better to reference it by name, or use an array?

Comment: @Jack: I'm not looking for a loop

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
 for(var key in obj) break;
 // "key" is the first key here
```

Comment: That's a very smart solution.

Answer (score 11):

```
var list = {
    item1: "a",
    item2: "b",
    item3: "c",
    item4: "d"
};
```

is equivalent to

```
var list = {
    item2: "b",
    item1: "a",
    item3: "c",
    item4: "d"
};
```

So there is no first element.
If you want first element you should use array.

Comment: That's right, but stereofrog's answer gives me what I want!. I wouldn't say "there is no first", I would say "there is no ordering or indexing on object members". Anything coming first is first any way.

Comment: @valipour: So why does your question say *"I want to get the first member of this object"* if you don't care if you get the first item as defined by your ordering? Now it sounds like you're actually asking for a single member, irrespective of the order you defined.

Answer (score 2):

Even though some implementations of JavaScript uses lists to make object, they are supposed to be unordered maps.

So there is no first one.

Comment: That's right, but stereofrog's answer gives me what I want!. I wouldn't say "there is no first", I would say "there is no ordering or indexing on object members". Anything coming first is first any way.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-json-object)

You can use the following to get the desired key.

```
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
}
```

You need to use an array if you want to access elements in an indexed way.