# How to access an anonymous JSON attribute?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "Files": {
             "Lines": {
                    "198": {
                           "firstline": "sometext"
                    }
             }
    }
}
```

and the value "198" is dynamic and changes. How can I access the "firstline" property easily without knowing "198" in the following code:

```
var schema = JSON.parse(fileContents); 
console.log(schema.Files.Lines.????.firstline);
```

Comment: Will `198` be the only key in that level of the hierarchy?

Comment: Dominic, No. But I do want to access always the first key.

Comment: @user971956: While the keys in JSON might have an order, they are not ordered when converted to a JavaScript object, so you cannot access "the first property". Btw. your question has actually nothing to do with JSON, but with JavaScript objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access the first property of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/access-the-first-property-of-an-object)

Comment: This is a really elegant little solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/983298/231995

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few lines will do it:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(your_json);
var lines = obj.Files.Lines;
var keys = Object.keys(lines);
var keyICareAbout = keys[0];
var info  = lines[keyICareAbout];
```

**Note:** This solution relies on some newer javascript features. For `JSON` to work in all browsers, you will need Douglas Crockford's `json2.js` from [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). For `Object.keys` to work in all browsers, use this shim from [Mozilla's JS docuentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
if(!Object.keys) Object.keys = function(o){
 if (o !== Object(o))
      throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
 var ret=[],p;
 for(p in o) if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,p)) ret.push(p);
 return ret;
}
```

**Edit:** Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xNj7L/3/). Now updated with cross browser compatability measures and accessing data dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, so now I potentially have the key, do I need to iterate over all members to grab its sub values or can I directly access them now that I know its name?

Comment: you can access its members from its name. Just do `lines[keyICareAbout]`. I'll add it to the jsFiddle.

Comment: No problem! Updated jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you decide to specifically use an `Array` at the `Lines` level, there is no way to guarantee what order they will come out it.

Using `for..in` or `Object.keys`, you can enumerate the properties, and just exit out of the loop on the first iteration. But again, there is no guarantee what order they will come out in, it depends upon the implementation. (although many times, it'll be what you expect)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what the key will be, it might be useful to return your data as an array:

```
{
    "Files": {
        "Lines": [{
            "id": "198",
            "firstline": "sometext"}]
    }
}

var schema = JSON.parse(fileContents); 
console.log(schema.Files.Lines[0].firstline); //sometext
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
schema.Files.Lines.properties[0].firstline
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/KBj2G/

(Yes, the `'properties'` getter has to be implemented manually... )