# in JavaScript get first object member name

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access the first property of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/access-the-first-property-of-an-object)

I just want to know if there is a better way to get the first member name in a object like:

```
var x={a:1};
func(x);//will return 'a'
```

I programmed a small function but I'm not satisfied, i think that there is a better way

what i did is :

```
var get_member = function(obj){for (i in obj){if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) return i;}};
```

Comment: the "first element" is not a reliable concept for an object. it's not like an array. This is a MU-question :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Answer (score 0):

**Supposing your "first member" is defined by addition order :**

There is no guaranteed order in javascript object properties, so you shouldn't do this even while it currently work on most browsers.

Look at this related question : [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)

So the proper ECMAScript compliant implementation for first added member can't exist.

**Supposing you have an intrinsic "first member" definition based on key (or value) :**

If what you want is based on a given order, let's say alphabetical for example, you can do this :

```
var keys = [];
for (k in x) {
   keys.push(k);   
}
keys.sort();
return keys[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "first" property of an object, they have no order. You can only get "some" property by using

```
function func(obj) {
    if (Object(obj) !== obj)
        throw new Error("not an object");
    for (var prop in obj)
        return prop;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the better way to get the first key from the object.

var x= {a:1};

```
for (var key in x) break;
```

console.log(key);