# Get the value of the only entry in a hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access the first property of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/access-the-first-property-of-an-object)

I have a hash `h` decoded from `JSON`, and it contains only one entry. I don't care (and I don't need to know) about the key for this entry, but just want to get its corresponding value.

What is the fastest method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much, much nicer if you knew what the key was, but if not, this should work

```
var value;
for (var key in h){
    value = h[key];
    break;
}
```

Comment: when you say 'nicer', you mean in terms of performance or something else?

Comment: In terms of code quality.  In terms of performance I can't imagine it making the least difference.