# JSON Object return values based on position

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON object

```
var obj = {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}
```

And I can return values using `obj.firstName` etc. But in my case I might not know the name of the header but I know its position. Is there a way I can return the value using its position? e.g. `obj.1`

Comment: JavaScript objects don't have order.

Comment: Run a for/in loop and assign the values to an Array. The problem is some Browsers will alphabetize the Object properties by name, so you might not get consistent results.

Comment: @PHPglue even though ECMAscript specifically defines no order, many browsers do use an ordering such as "insert order".  I never heard of one that does it alphabetically, though.

Comment: My Objects are almost never in the order I make them when looking in Firebug.

Comment: Are you perhaps a PHP programmer, where key/value arrays also have numeric indices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you think of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or a `for..in` loop

You can't rely on its position, because depending on the browser implementation, object keys are sorted in lexicographic order OR not, ecma5 does not force to do either way.

Comment: that's understanding it - ES5 _specifically says_ that an object is an _unordered set of key/value pairs_.  Any ordering you happen to get is therefore an implementation issue.

Answer (score 2):

JSON don't have indexes, what you can do is create an array of indexes:

```
var indexes = []
for(var key in obj) {
  indexes.push(key);
}
```

And then use those keys to access the JSON elements, note that `for...in` return the keys in random order.

Comment: "_and then use those keys_" ... in whatever random order `for ... in ...` dropped them there...

Comment: I started the answer with _"JSON don't have indexes"_, perhaps what I wrote after gives the idea that there's some ordering to it?

Comment: Your answer could still give the OP the impression that the elements will end up in the array in some deterministic order.

Comment: So essentially there is no way to do it?

Comment: Alnitak comment was pretty informing: "_ES5 specifically says that an object is an unordered set of key/value pairs_" and aduch answer also: "_object keys are sorted in lexicographic order OR not, ecma5 does not force to do either way._", so no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509718/1443478

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal' };
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]; //returns 'someVal'
```