# Javascript - Get the associative array key value

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with one key value as given below -

```
var a = {};
a.x = "randomvalue";
```

My requirement is to get access the value "randomvalue", but the catch is I dont know that the property name is "x".

Simplest way to get the value??

Comment: Iterate the keys of the object, return the key if the corresponding value matches

Comment: who creates the object? where does it come from and how is it created?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11509718/34806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var v, i;
var a = {};
a.x = "randomvalue";
for (x in a) {
  if a[x] === "randomvalue" {
    v = x;
    i = "randomvalue";
  }
}
```

Then `v` contains the object key and `i` contains the object  value (although you don't really need it).

Or, if you know the value index:

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal' };
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]; //returns 'someVal'
```