# How can I get value of first key/value pair in forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, key

I have the following forEach loop to iterate over stored jQuery selectors:

```
contentExtras = [
   { right: $right_mask, start: aVariable, end: 0 },
   { right: $le, start: 0, end: bVariable },
   { left: $left_mask, start: cVariable, end: 0 }
];
```

Now I can do:

```
contentExtras.forEach( function( item ) {
    item.right.css( { top: item.start } );
} );
```

or:

```
contentExtras.forEach( function( item ) {
    item.left.css( { bottom: item.start } );
} );
```

Now I am looking for a way to do get the value of every **first** key/value pair independent of wether it is "right" or "left".

In the way that I could do something like:

```
contentExtras.forEach( function( item ) {
    item.["both left and right"].css( { bottom: item.start } );
} );
```

I tried things like: item.[0] but without success.
Does this explain sufficiently what I need? Thanks in advance for help!

**EDIT:**

So this is the part of the answer of Rayon that solved my problem:

```
contentExtras.forEach( function( item ) {
    item[Object.keys(item)[0]].doThingsWithItsValues()
} );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access the first property of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/access-the-first-property-of-an-object)

Comment: You are probably right :-( but I cannot get ahead of this anyhow. I am sorry, didn’t see the other question or could not see the similarity. Sorry again for that.

Comment: I learn: do not ask questions when you are not able to handle the answers. Or better do not ask questions when you don't know the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

*Or* just `||`(Logical OR) operators

```js
contentExtras = [{
  right: '$right_mask',
  start: '-rightX',
  end: 0
}, {
  right: '$le',
  start: 0,
  end: '-leX'
}, {
  left: '$left_mask',
  start: '-rightX',
  end: 0
}];

contentExtras.forEach(function(item) {
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; //Get the first key
  console.log(item[key])
    //OR
  console.log(item.left || item.right);
});
```

Comment: Thanks first of all! So I tried to do: contentExtras.forEach( function( item ) {
      Object.keys(item)[0].myFunction();
   } ); but get the error:TypeError: Object.keys(item)[0].myFunction is not a function. (In 'Object.keys(item)[0].myFunction()', 'Object.keys(item)[0].myFunction' is undefined)

Comment: Sorry. I am not so fast. Put some function for the jQuery selector I’d like to retrieve.

Comment: @Garavani, Unable to get you :(

Comment: No wonder! I am sorry. I’ll edit my question and try to get clearer! Moment!

Comment: @Garavani, If you could access the property(`$right_mask/$left_mask`), What is the concern ?

Comment: I tried to be not specific in my question to come to the point, but I see I am not able to explain. Sorry for that. Forget about it! I’ll find another way.

Comment: The problem seems to be the ' ' that I cannot have for my values the way my code works. I need the selectors without ' '. Your code is cool but I need the value of the first key each time not the key.

Comment: @Garavani I added quotes to demonstarate how it works.. You are suppose to understand than just copy paste it.. Those variables were undefined in your provided script..

Comment: Can you extend your code that it gives me the **value** of each first key (so in my case the stored jQuery selector) not the key itself?

Comment: @Garavani execute the snippet, you will get the VALUE in console..(console.log statements results the value)

Comment: I am sorry. No, it does not work for my case. I can do: contentExtras.forEach( function( item ) {
    item.right.someFunction();
   } ); but I get errors when doing: contentExtras.forEach( function( item ) {
    Object.keys(item)[0].someFunction();
   } );

Comment: function( item ) {     item[Object.keys(item)[0]].someFunction();    }

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot for your patience, Rayon! Genius!

Comment: @Garavani You did test my patience mate Glad to help you!