# JSON, parsing sub-objects with different names

Tags: javascript, json

so I am trying to parse a JSON response:

```
{
"success":true,
"rgInventory":{
"7058200129":{
"id":"7058200129",
"classid":"1690096482",
"instanceid":"0",
"amount":"1",
"pos":1
},
"7038515091":{
"id":"7038515091",
"classid":"310776543",
"instanceid":"302028390",
"amount":"1",
"pos":2
},
"6996242662":{
"id":"6996242662",
"classid":"310781169",
"instanceid":"302028390",
"amount":"1",
"pos":3
},
```

So I need to access the rgInventory to acccess the subsets. The problem is that I try this as my code to parse the JSON:

```
obj.rgInventory[0]
```

This normally works for me but it doesn't work this time. The issue is that this is a snippet of the JSON, there are roughly 200 of these responses. How can I parse all of them dynamically?

I only need help getting the data. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)? Also `rgInventory` is an object literal.

Comment: @FrankerZ yea sorry about that, I was going to choose an answer but I had to wait three minutes, I then just forgot about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rgInventory` is an object, not an array, so it can't be accessed like an array. Notice the `{` directly after the colon instead of a `[`?

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509718/4875631) to get the first element in an object:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]); //logs 'bar'
```

[Here](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them) is a great tutorial on the differences between arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not a valid JSON, but anyway you have shared here a JSON object which we can parse it and access sub objects by their keys like this:

```
var rgInventory = json["rgInventory"];
```

This is a **DEMO snippet**:

```js
var json = {
"success":true,
"rgInventory":{
"7058200129":{
"id":"7058200129",
"classid":"1690096482",
"instanceid":"0",
"amount":"1",
"pos":1
},
"7038515091":{
"id":"7038515091",
"classid":"310776543",
"instanceid":"302028390",
"amount":"1",
"pos":2
},
"6996242662":{
"id":"6996242662",
"classid":"310781169",
"instanceid":"302028390",
"amount":"1",
"pos":3
}}};

var rgInventory = json["rgInventory"];
alert(rgInventory[6996242662].id);
```

Comment: Yea, its weird since I am using the steam api and they say it is JSON, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, and as you can see the sub elements are organized as key/value elements and not as an array so in any case you need to access their values by Key/Name.