# How to use Object.values() on server side in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

`Object.values()` received following error:

> TypeError: Object.values is not a function.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748445/uncaught-typeerror-object-values-is-not-a-function-javascript) question on stackoverflow - I see that `Object.values()` is not supported in all browsers.

But I am using the function in Node.js on server side - How can I use `Object.values()` in Node.js it seems so intuitive like `Object.keys()`?

Comment: "But I am using it on server side code" - using Node.js?

Comment: question was to find how to use Object.values() in node.js as mentioned in title. I have edited question to make it explicit in body as well. why the downvote its not the duplicate ?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Due to the unspecific nature, I thought it was a duplicate, which has now been retracted.

Comment: as mentioned previously it wasn't unspecific - title clearly states the intent

Comment: because sometimes JS is actually stupid :) Object.values should have existed a decade ago lol

Comment: I'm using node version `node -v
v9.8.0` and I still get that same error.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`Object.values` is a new feature in [ES2017](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.values). It is very bleeding edge. Node.js has full [support for it](http://node.green/) from version 7.0.

6.8.1 supports it, but it is considered unstable and is locked behind the `--harmony` flag.

You can either:

- Upgrade to the latest Node.js LTS and use `--harmony`
- Upgrade to the latest Node.js Current
- Use a polyfill

Comment: Use `node -v` to find out what version of Node you're using.

Answer (score 21):

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) is in status "Draft" for the version ECMAScript2017 and here the specification: [ECMAScript 2017 Draft (ECMA-262) The definition of 'Object.values' in that specification.](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.values).

The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

Without change nothing in your NodeJS enviroment you can achive the same by using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) that returns an array of keys and chaining a [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to return the desired array of the Object's values:

```js
const obj = { 
    foo: "bar", 
    baz: 42 
  },
  // Object.values()
  objValues = Object.values(obj),
  // Object.keys() and map(),
  objKeysMap = Object.keys(obj).map((k) => obj[k]);

console.log('objValues:', objValues);
console.log('objKeysMap:', objKeysMap);
```

Answer (score 12):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/) is a pretty awesome tool to simplify your JavaScript code. You can use `_.values`:

```js
var _ = require('lodash');
_.values({ a: 'a' }) // => ['a']
```

Answer (score 11):

I am developing a AWS Lambda and now I stumbeled over the same problem and I solved it by this simple line (assuming a is the object)

`const values = Object.keys(a).map(k => a[k]);`

Comment: You should check if it's not already defined for future proofing.. we're actually already in the future where it exists in newer node versions :) No reason to overwrite it when it's already defined.

Answer (score 4):

3 alternative to go around if you don't want to upgrade node

1. mapping keys as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830257/alternative-version-for-object-values)
2. using lodash as another answer by @sakovias
3. using this [object.values npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.values)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a polyfill that kicks in only when it's not already defined:

```
const objectToValuesPolyfill = (object) => {
  return Object.keys(object).map(key => object[key]);
};
Object.values = Object.values || objectToValuesPolyfill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Node.js to the latest version. It'll enable you to use

```
Object.values()
```

You can get it from the official site: 
https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Or use [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#values)

```
var _ = require('underscore');

const obj = { 
    foo: "bar", 
    baz: 42 
  };

console.log(_.values(obj));
// ["bar",42]
```