# TypeError: Object.values is not a function -- How to correctly polyfill with babel-preset-env in jest?

Tags: jestjs

I get the following error after upgrading to Jest v20 where they removed the automatic `babel-polyfill` due to memory leaks:

`TypeError: Object.values is not a function`

I realize I need to polyfill this on my own now, I am using `babel-preset-env` and have the following `.babelrc` file:

```
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "react",
        "stage-3",
        ["env", {
          "targets": {
            "browsers": [
              "firefox >= 36",
              "chrome >= 38",
              "opera >= 25",
              "safari >= 9",
              "ios >= 9"
            ],
            "node": "6.11.4"
          },
          "useBuiltIns": "usage",
          "include": ["es7.object.values"],
          "debug": true
        }],
        "jest"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties"
      ],
    }
  }
```

I can see that `es7.object.values` is being polyfilled in the debug output:

```
Using polyfills:
  ...
  es7.object.values {"chrome":"38","firefox":"36","ios":"9","safari":"9","node":"6.11.4"}
```

But I am still getting the error message, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the options are:

1. **bump node version** to the one supporting `Object.values` (which
   seems to be `7.0` judging from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421825/how-to-use-object-values-on-server-side-in-node-js)),
2. **polyfill** it using [`babel-polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) (via `import 'babel-polyfill'` in `setupTests.js` file).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Node version was the reason.
I just updated the `node 6` to `node 7` and it fixed.