# Get all the values of a namespace in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

**Node Version:** 6.11.3

**Typescript Version:** 2.1.6

We have a bunch of enums in our project that mostly look like this:

```
export type ThingType = "thing1" | "thing2";

export namespace ThingType {
    export const THING_ONE = "thing1";
    export const THING_TWO = "thing2";
}
```

I want to expose these values in an endpoint for consumers of the endpoints that require these string values. So I've made an endpoint that looks like this:

```
const enums = {
    thingType: ThingType,
    ...
}
```

Which returns json looking like:

```
"data": {
    "thingType": {
        "THING_ONE": "thing1",
        "THING_TWO": "thing2"
    }
}
```

I want it to be output like:

```
"data": {
    "thingType": ["thing1", "thing2"]
}
```

For a plain javascript object, that would be fairly easy, I'd just add `values()` to the end of `ThingType` in my endpoint. But `values()` does not exist on namespaces or enums in TS. I haven't found anything in the [docs on namespaces in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) but I feel there's gotta be something that would let me get the enum values easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Namespaces are compiled into plain javacsript objects, so [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) works as expected (in the environment that supports `Object.values` of course):

```
export type ThingType = "thing1" | "thing2";

export namespace ThingType {
    export const THING_ONE = "thing1";
    export const THING_TWO = "thing2";
}

const enums = {
    thingType: Object.values(ThingType)

}
console.(enums);
```

shows

```
{ thingType: ['thing1', 'thing2'] }
```

If `Object.values` is not available it gets a little more verbose:

```
const enums = {
    thingType: Object.keys(ThingType).map(k => ThingType[k])

}
```

Comment: What version of ts? I'm getting an error saying `values does not exist on type ObjectConstructor` :/

Comment: Ahh, shoot, looks like its node7+, we are on node 6 right now
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40421941/1329321

Comment: @MikeManfrin - Simple workaround for `object.values` being unavailable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748445/uncaught-typeerror-object-values-is-not-a-function-javascript/38748490#38748490

Comment: Yeah -- but that requires a map for each; which isn't terrible, just less concise than I was aiming for. I am using lodash as per the suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421825/how-to-use-object-values-on-server-side-in-node-js but just bummed there's nothing native that can handle it.

Comment: Going to leave the question up just in case someone has a deeper understanding of ts that may point out something part of TS itself that can do this.

Comment: I added workaround almost identical to the one suggested by  tymeJV. `Object.values()` is not considered part of the language, it's part of the library, and TypeScript does not in general provide polyfills or replacements for missing library features -  [with some exceptions](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/12/16/typescript-2-1-external-helpers-library).  But you may want to look into [--emitDecoratorMetadata](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) option to see if it emits something for namespaces and enums (I have no idea honestly)