# Object.values() in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm attempting to use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) in one of my Firebase Cloud Functions, but it isn't recognized as a function. I assume this means that es7 functions aren't available on Firebase Cloud Functions. My question is two-fold:

First, is this true? Second, I recognize that the function isn't supported by some browsers, but I wonder if that's important for Firebase Cloud Functions. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to node.green, Firebase only supports the LTS version of Node which is currently at the version 6.10.x and `Object.values` is still behind experimental flag in Node 6.10.x.

Hope this cleared your doubt!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748445/uncaught-typeerror-object-values-is-not-a-function-javascript) that recommends using the `Object.keys` function and chaining it to the built in `map` function that comes with the array prototype.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to get around using Object.keys.

Answer (score 0):

Node 8 is available for cloud functions now. Try upgrading your environment.

You probably just need to:

- Add "engines": { "node": "8" } to your /functions/package.json. [Example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/stripe/functions/package.json).

In case it still doesn't work:

- Upgrade your firebase-functions to the latest version
- Upgrade firebase-tools to the latest version