# How to setup next.js?

Tags: next.js

I just follow the step from offical website:

[https://nextjs.org/docs/](http://How%20to%20setup%20next.js?)

step 1.

```
npm install --save next react react-dom
```

step 2.  Add a script to package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  }
}
```

step 3. 
Add ./pages/index.js inside project:

```
export default () => <div>Welcome to next.js!</div>
```

Then I ran npm run dev and got the error:

```
/Users/jh/Documents/worksapce/react/nextJs/test1/node_modules/webpackbar/dist/index.js:55
    const hasRunning = () => Object.values(sharedState).find(s => s.isRunning);
                                ^

TypeError: Object.values is not a function
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is sharedState, is it an object or an array?

Comment: See this answer, I don't think this is related to next.js  per se. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748445/uncaught-typeerror-object-values-is-not-a-function-javascript

Comment: @ArrowHead Hello, thanks for help. I found that my node version is too old, so that error happen.  It works after node updated.

Comment: I am happy you found the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to your node version. Please upgrade your node version. Node >= 7.0.0 fully supported this.

Answer (score 0):

you can setup easily with this comment.

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

you can check in here.
https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation