# How to get the first key of an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object and I want to access the first element of that object, so first, I need to get the first key of that object. I have two ways to do it but I'm looking for a better way.

**The first is:**

```
var firstKey = Object.keys(myObject)[0];
```

but `Object.keys` will return an array of all the keys. So if I want just the first key, this method will be too expensive for my quest (especially if `myObject` have too many keys).

**The second method is:**

```
var firstKey = null;
for(var key in myObject){
    firstKey = key;
    break;
}
```

this works just fine and it's better than the first one but I think it's hideous (`for`, `break` and all that mess just to get the first key).

**So**

I was wondering if there is a much elegant way to get the first key? Something like:

```
var firstKey from myObject;
```

**EDIT:**

I don't care about the ordering I just want to get whatever the first key is.

**EDIT2:**

I have an object that holds some informations (lets say, for example, a person's name is a key, his email will be the value). Let's say I have a placeholder where some name and it's email adress are printed. If I press delete, I delete that entry (`delete myObject[name];`), then I need to fill that placeholder with another name and email (I don't care who anyone will do), so the first (or whatever the first is now) will do.

Comment: What do you mean by "first element of that object"?

Comment: The order of `Object.keys` and `for...in` is implementation dependent.

Comment: There really is no "first" key in an object. E.g. `Object.keys(myObject)[0]` will give you the key that was created first in most browsers, but this is not certain.

Comment: As far as I know, `Object.keys(myObject)[0]` is the most common way. There isn't any fancy way of doing it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access the first property of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/access-the-first-property-of-an-object)

Comment: @Oriol: The order of `Object.keys` is implementation dependent prior to ES5. After ES5 it is defined in the spec. I know, stupid to have an unordered collection to have order but that's what people asked for. Currently all browsers and node.js support the specified ordering but transcompilers like babel etc. don't support it.

Comment: BTW, even if the ordering of properties in objects are specified you should not depend on it. The specified ordering is: keys that look like integers always come first and are ordered numerically, then all other properties are ordered by insertion order. So, if someone adds a numeric key to your object then you're screwed.

Comment: @slebetman [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219/1529630) No

Comment: lets just call the order "random"...

Comment: I want just to get any key from the object without using the above methods because one is expensive and the other is hideous.

Comment: @Oriol: Ah, cool. I wish they'd make the language stronger. The `as if` phrasing has been used to argue for specified ordering for a long time.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir This may sound silly, but what do you mean by "any key"? You simply want a key from an object without caring _at all_ which one it is? What about empty objects?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Actually, since `var` is function scope you can just do `for (var firstKey in myObject) break;` but that's rather hackish and generally won't pass code review (unless you're with a bunch of old-school C programmers)

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein check **EDIT2** above.

Comment: Don't be an idealist. Computers are fast enough for these basic operations.

Comment: @undefined I'm not an idealist. I was just looking for a better way to do it. Now that I haven't I'm sticking to the second method.

Comment: Well, I said that because I personally have dedicated many hours for optimizing my code unnecessarily during my career as a developer. That was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from [MDN's documentation on `for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (I highlight):

> The `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in ***arbitrary*** order.

And the [documentation on `Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) has:

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the ***same order*** as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

So the concept of *first* key is a fuzzy one. A lot has already been said about property order in JavaScript objects. You might want to go through [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

You could consider to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of a plain object with (apparently) dynamic properties. A `Map` also stores key/value pairs, but guarantees that insertion order is maintained.

Here is an example on how you could set some key/value pairs, and then get the first one. Then it deletes the first, and the next one becomes the first:

```js
let mp = new Map().set('x', 1)
                  .set('y', 3)
                  .set('z', 14);

let key = mp.keys().next().value;
console.log('before delete, the first key is: ', key);

mp.delete(key);

key = mp.keys().next().value;
console.log('after delete, the first key is: ', key);
```

Although the call to [`keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) may give the impression that it will first generate a list of all keys, this is not true: it returns an iterator, not an array, and only the call to `next` will actually fetch one.

Answer (score 2):

The only approach which won't collect all properties in an array is the `for...in` one.

You can always move it to a function for better abstraction:

```
function firstKey(obj) {
  for (var key in obj)
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key))
      return key;
}
firstKey({a: 1}); // "a"
firstKey({});     // undefined
```

However, note that it won't be well defined, because `for...in` and `Object.keys` use an implementation-dependent order.

It would be better if [[OwnPropertyKeys]] returned an iterator and there was some way to expose it:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNamesIterator(obj).next().value; // this does not exist :(
```

Comment: This still uses the hideous method. Wrapping it in a function is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah an iterator will be great. But untill they make one I think I'll stick with the hideous method.

Comment: you probably need a check for `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @NinaScholz but to use `hasOwnProperty` you'll have to provide a key (which I don't have, because I'm looking for it).

Comment: @NinaScholz I guess that depends on how "first key" is defined, but OK, I added a `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` check.