# How To Sort Data From An Object In Vue templates?

Tags: vue.js

I am using Firebase. There data is stored as objects with unique keys.

I want to keep these keys for updating purposes.

However I also want to sort the data like an array, when rendering it in my Vue-templates.

The data looks like:

```
topics:
  - [firebase-push-key]
    - title
    - text
    - ...
```

I want to sort it in my template like:

```
<template v-for="topic in $store.state.forum.topics">
  ...
</template>
```

`$store.state.forum.topics` should be sorted by the value `title`.

EDIT:

This Vuex-mutation does the job:

```
retrieveTopics(state) {
  topics.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const object = snapshot.val()
    var array = Object.keys(object).map((key) => {
      return { [key]: object[key] }
    })
    state.forum.topics = array
  })
}
```

But how can I iterate over the resulting array in a vue template?

this is the data structure:

```
[ { "-Kmbspn0WYBlNXfmfVlR": { "slug": "arne", "title": "Arne" } }, { "-KmbsqiG_9uXzRhHrnXZ": { "slug": "tati", "title": "Tati" } }, { "-KmbsrllgJzV7BA_NeCO": { "slug": "abel", "title": "Abel" } } ]
```

Comment: Use a computed value.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: Could you give an example of your data and how you want to sort it?

Comment: shure. Wait a second.

Comment: The eternal second..

Answer (score 3):

Something like this. Here I'm obviously not using Vuex, but you could use a Vuex getter. If you need the `id` of the topic in the sorted objects, you could add it in your map.

```js
console.clear()

// topics:
//   - [firebase-push-key]
//     - title
//     - text
//     - ...
  
const topics = {
  "1234":{
    title: "Ziss one starts with Z",
    text: "text1"
  },
  "2345":{
    title: "M is for middle",
    text: "text2"
  },
  "3456":{
    title: "Alpha title",
    text: "text3"
  }
}

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    topics
  },
  methods:{
    sortProperty(prop){
      return (a,b) => {
        if (a[prop] < b[prop])
          return -1;
        if (a[prop] > b[prop])
          return 1;
        return 0;       
      }
    }
  },
  computed:{
    sortedTopics(){
      return Object.keys(this.topics)
        .map(t => {
          this.$set(this.topics[t], 'key', t)
          return this.topics[t]
        })
        .sort(this.sortProperty('title'))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="topic in sortedTopics">
    {{topic}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Here is an example that handles your updated data structure.

```js
const topics = [{
  "-Kmbspn0WYBlNXfmfVlR": {
    "slug": "arne",
    "title": "Arne"
  }
}, {
  "-KmbsqiG_9uXzRhHrnXZ": {
    "slug": "tati",
    "title": "Tati"
  }
}, {
  "-KmbsrllgJzV7BA_NeCO": {
    "slug": "abel",
    "title": "Abel"
  }
}]

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    topics
  },
  methods: {
    sortByObjectProperty(prop, getter) {
      return (a, b) => {
        a = getter(a), b = getter(b)
        if (a[prop] < b[prop])
          return -1;
        if (a[prop] > b[prop])
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortedTopics() {
      const getter = v => v[Object.keys(v)[0]]
      const sorter = this.sortByObjectProperty("title", getter)
      return this.topics.sort(sorter)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="topic in sortedTopics">
    {{topic}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In this code (as in the above code), `sortByObjectProperty` is a sort function *generator*. You pass it any property name it will generate a sorting function for objects that have that property. In order to handle the data structure you have in your `topics` I added a `getter` parameter which is a function you can use to tell the sorter *how* to get the object it needs to sort.

I was worried initially about the performance of `v[Object.keys(v)[0]]` but that seems to be addressed, at least my own satisfaction,  in the [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509718/38065).

If you don't have to support IE, or you are using something that compiles to javascript that supports it, you could also define a default for the `getter` parameter in cases where you don't need to sort by a nested object.

```
sortByObjectProperty(prop, getter = g => g) {...}
```

Which you could then use as

```
const sorter = this.sortByObjectProperty("someProperty")
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I keep the Firebase-Push-Key if I want to update the piece of data??

Comment: @TimoMüller I mentioned how you might in the post, but I updated the code to show it.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could comment it out ! thanks

Comment: @TimoMüller I'm sorry, I don't understand. I updated the code to actually add the key.

Comment: isn't there a better solution, one that is one line, and not so much boilerplate code ?!?!

Comment: @TimoMüller Maybe someone will come along and give you a better answer. This one works. I answered a question from you a few days ago I still have zero feedback on. Good luck :)