# In JavaScript, do there exist any ways to get a property of an object without using dot notation or bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Let's say I have a simple object `a = {b: 2}`. I know of two ways to get the value of property b of a:

Dot notation: `a.b // 2`

and

Bracket Notation: `a['b'] // 2`

Practicality aside, does there exist any way to get the value of b from object a without using either of these two methods (dot notation and bracket notation)? [MDN's page on Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) only lists the 2 methods.

---

It's just a curiosity I had. I know there exist obscure ways to call functions without parenthesis, eg

```
parseInt`5.1`
```

I wanted to see if a similarly obscure thing was possible for Property access.

Comment: Is there a reason for this question?

Comment: It depends upon what you are trying to do.  For example, in your limited example `a[0] //2` as well.

Comment: @Sablefoste did you try executing that?

Comment: @phil, right, it gives `undefined`.  But also the point is it could be used in a reference.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24061635/1408137

Comment: @Sablefoste for a plain object? I don't think so

Comment: @Phil It's just a curiosity I had. I know there exist obscure ways to call functions without parenthesis (ex. double backticks). I wanted to see if a similarly obscure thing was possible for Property access.

Comment: You should probably explain that in your question. Right now, it just seems pointless since brackets and dots work just fine. Also, what's this double-backtick syntax you speak of?

Comment: `parseInt\`5.1\` // 5`

Comment: Don't overlook the power of bracket notation, though. There is so much that can be accomplished with that feature.

Comment: @phil My favorite example of how weird javascript is involves backticks: `Function\`$${\`alert($$)\`}$$\`\`$${\`wat\`}$$\``

Comment: This is hilarious; I don't think there is a reason, but a definitive reference may be helpful for someone???

Comment: @Rafael Are you talking about the alert statement? Because if so, I'd be happy to explain how it works! Although the comment section might not leave enough space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not *exactly* the same as accessing a property, but it’s nevertheless a sneaky way to get at an object’s contents if you are using the latest JS (es6+). All the hip JS kids are doing it these days.

```
const { b } = a
console.log(b) // 2
```

This is called *destructuring*, it works with objects and arrays, and you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: And here I am using functions like some kind of grandpa. Nice answer :D

Comment: Both answers are really insightful, but I'll accept this one since it avoids using any dot syntax or bracket notation entirely. Now I wonder if there is a way to use destructuring if we can't type the variable name directly, but rather have a string with its name. Like: `const a = {b: 2}; const c = 'b'; // somehow access b using destructuring using the variable c`. Interesting stuff to consider. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Lucien you sure can... `let { b: c } = a`. This is handy for property names that don't make good variables, eg `{ '.id': 2 }`. Edit: I may have misunderstood

Comment: These are the droids you are looking for: https://tylermcginnis.com/videos/computed-property-names/

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`:

```
const object1 = {
  property1: 42
}

const descriptor1 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object1, 'property1');
console.log(descriptor1.value);//42
```

It doesn't search through the prototype chain, but it works on immediate properties and worth noting, for you can make recursive functions searching the prototype chain with it :)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, too. Bracket and dot-notation usually work fine, but sometimes you need to be able to hack and mock stuff for testing.

Answer (score 4):

First thing that springs to mind is [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
const a = {b: 2}

Object.values(a).forEach(v => {
  console.info(v)
})
```

But how would you know what key you're accessing?

There's also [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) I suppose

```js
const a = {b: 2}

Object.entries(a).forEach(entry => {
  // entries are [key, value] arrays
  let value = entry.pop()
  let key = entry.pop()
  console.info(key, ':', value)
})
```

Note: I used `Array.prototype.pop()` so as not to use *"bracket notation"*.

Comment: Nothing prompts creativity quite like a restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of lodash 'get' and 'set' without using dot or bracket notation; useful for passing security scans.

https://jsfiddle.net/5amtL8zx/17/

```
/* lodash implementation of 'get', 'set', and 'unset' without dot or bracket notation
  * - supports getting and setting 'prop1.2' array element but not with brackets: 'prop1.[2]'
  */
isObjectKey = (obj, key) => {
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype && /string|number/.test(typeof key);
}

isArrayNumber = (obj, key) => {
  const isKey = /string|number/.test(typeof key), path = isKey ? String(key).split('.') : [], prop = isKey && path.length > 1 ? path.shift() : '';
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Array.prototype && isKey && !isNaN(prop);
}

isValid = (obj, key) => {
  const isObj = isObjectKey(obj, key), isArr = isArrayNumber(obj, key);
  return isObj || isArr;
}

define = (obj, key, value) => {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, String(key), { value, writable: true, configurable: true, enumerable: true  });
}

get = (obj, key, value) => {
  if (!isValid(obj, key)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let path = String(key).split('.'), prop = path.shift(), result = new Map(Object.entries(obj)).get(prop);
  return path.length && typeof result !== 'undefined' ? get(result, path.join('.'), value) : result || value;
}

set = (obj, key, value) => {
  if (!isValid(obj, key)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let path = key.split('.'), prop = path.shift();
  if (!(prop in obj)) {
    define(obj, prop, {});
  }
  const result = get(obj, prop);
  return path.length && isValid(result, path.join('.')) ? set(result, path.join('.'), value) : define(obj, prop, value);
}

unset = (obj, key) => {
  if (!isValid(obj, key)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let path = key.split('.'), prop = path.shift();
  if (!(prop in obj)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (path.length) {
    let result = get(obj, prop);
    result = unset(result, path.join('.'));
    set(obj, prop, result);
    return obj;
  } else {
    const { [prop]: remove, ...rest } = obj;
    return rest;
  }
}

let obj = {};
set(obj, 'prop1.prop2', 'value1');
console.log(Object.entries(obj));
console.log(get(obj, 'prop1.prop2'));
const prop1 = get(obj, 'prop1');
set(prop1, 'prop2', 'value2');
console.log(get(obj, 'prop1.prop2'));
set(obj, 'prop3', [1, 2, 3]);
console.log(get(obj, 'prop3'));
console.log(get(obj, 'prop3.2'));
console.log(get(obj.prop3, 0));
set(obj, 'prop3.3', 4);
console.log(get(obj, 'prop3.3'));
set(obj, 'prop4', [{'name': 'Bob'}]);
console.log(get(obj, 'prop4.0'));
unset(obj, 'prop4.0.name')
console.log(get(obj, 'prop4.0'));
//[["prop1", {
//  prop2: "value1"
//}]]
//"value1"
//"value2"
//[1, 2, 3]
//3
//1
//4
//{
//  name: "Bob"
//}
//{ ... }
```