# How to get the first value of the first object in the first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to understand if when I have a first element from the first object in the first array.
The structure is this:
`let arr = [[{"a": 1, "b": 2}], [{"c": 3, "d": 4}]]`

I've done this (see below), but maybe there is shorter solution

```js
let arr = [[{"a": 1, "b": 2}], [{"c": 3, "d": 4}]]

let newArr = [];
//arr[0] - the first array
arr[0].map((item, index) => {
  //pushing items into empty arr to get the first value
  for (let key in item) {
    newArr.push(item[key]);
  }
  console.log(newArr[0]);
});
```

I need the output like:
- the first value of the firts object of the first array.
- then other values.

Comment: `arr[0][0].a` ?

Comment: First item in array: `arr[0]`. First item in array, first item in that array: `arr[0][0]`. Its `a` property: `arr[0][0].a`. Is that what you're after? I'm a bit confused to be quite honest.

Comment: I think this `[{"a": 1, "b": 2}]` is the same of this `{"a": 1, "b": 2}`

Comment: @CalvinNunes I think the point is that she doesn't know the first property name, it can vary.

Comment: @GrafiCode Well one is an array and one is an object... Though, I agree that the array in such a case isn't serving a ton of purpose.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm after but the name of the first object property can vary.

Comment: @Barmar yes, could be the problem, but she says: *"the structure **is** this ..."*

Comment: @CodeManiac - Given that the marked duplicate confirms that the key is a random string, and that it's the only key in the object, the boundaries of that request don't present the same dangers that OP's does in regards to creation order. I'm not sure the answers are entirely adequate.

Comment: @TylerRoper is there anyway you can guaranty the retrieval of keys in sequence, they do have sequence [`property order`](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/), `object.values` and `for ... in` loops in same order, if you still feel duplicate aren't sufficient let me know will reopen

Comment: @CodeManiac The order is guaranteed, yes, but the guaranteed order isn't always *creation order*. See the second snippet in my answer below. If OP wants the "first property", they're going to be very surprised when the one returned is actually the *last* property. It seems like in the marked duplicate, they're retrieving the *only* key. In this question, OP wants the *first* key. Because one is reliant on order and one is not, in my opinion, there's a big difference :)

Comment: @TylerRoper you want me to reopen it ? is there any solution which can guaranty will return first property only  1) [`Valid key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties), 2) [`Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: @TylerRoper but object is not suitable data structure when order is important, option should be `Map`, `Array` or anything which holds order

Comment: @CodeManiac Well that's exactly my point. I think that that information is very important to this question, and the duplicate does not cover it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196589/discussion-between-code-maniac-and-tyler-roper).

Comment: @CodeManiac agreed, there is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/how-to-access-the-first-property-of-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the name, you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
let arr = [[{"a": 1, "b": 2}], [{"c": 3, "d": 4}]];
let result = Object.values(arr[0][0])[0];

console.log(result);
```

**HOWEVER, object property order is not always the same as its creation order.** Be warned that if your object has positive integer keys, *you cannot retrieve its creation order*.

```js
let arr = [[{"a": 1, "b": 2, 1: "I'm a positive integer key!"}], [{"c": 3, "d": 4}]];
let result = Object.values(arr[0][0])[0];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get the keys of an object, then get the first element of this. Then you can use that to access the property.

```js
let arr = [[{"a": 1, "b": 2}], [{"c": 3, "d": 4}]]

let newArr = [];
let firstKey = Object.keys(arr[0][0])[0];
console.log(arr[0][0][firstKey]);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first element"

Comment: `Object.keys()` returns an array, and an array has a first element.

Comment: Sure, but thats not necessarily the "first value of the object", as there is no such thing as "the first value of an object".

Comment: There is since ES6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: I know. But still it would be a good advice to tell the OP not to rely on it. Thats what your answer implies, and thus I consider it a bad answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flat()` and then `Object.values()` as follows:

```js
const arr = [[{"a": 1, "b": 2}], [{"c": 3, "d": 4}]]

console.log(Object.values((arr.flat()[0]))[0])
```

Comment: `Object.entries(arr.flat()[0]).flat()[1]` Is another way