# Retrieving JSON response data with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm calling an API in my application and need to drill down the JSON response. Within it there is a random string that changes so I can't hardcode the value. Is there a way I can access dataset1 no matter what the random string is?

```
{
    "data": {
        "Random String that Changes": { 
            "dataset1": {
                "date": {...}
            },
            "dataset2":{
                "date": {...}
            }
        }
    },
    "something else": {
        ...
    },
    "something else": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Previously I was hard coding the drill down like such:

```
this.props.data.randomData['Random String that Changes'].dataset1.date
```

Also tried:

```
this.props.data.randomData[0].dataset1.date
```

Comment: is `random string that changes` the ONLY property of `data`?

Comment: Yeah it is - thanks for replying!

Comment: @StephanieParker what problem actually are you facing?

Comment: what is data.randomData ? randomData is the key i guess which is changing dynamically. Alsp if its coming in props the key through which the props is holding this should be used  eg. this.props.KEY.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the object like this :

```
const obj = this.props.data;

obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].dataset1.date
```

Reference: [How to access the first property of an object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/how-to-access-the-first-property-of-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: `randomData` is random, not the word `randomData`

Comment: okay my bad will update the answer

Comment: @Bravo updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the keys of the object using

`const keys = Object.keys(this.props.data);`

Now `keys` is an array of all keys , but if you json always only has 1 key, you can get your data using

`this.props.data.randomData[keys[0]].dataset1.date`

Comment: randomData is not fixed. it is key that is dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You can get *dataset1*

```
const values = Object.values(this.props.data)
console.log(values[0]['dataset1'])
```

Make sure that your json includes the "Random String that changes" at first place as shown in your above format.

Reference: [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code for the solution.

```
var response = {
    "data": {
        "Random String that Changes": { 
            "dataset1": {
                "date": {...}
            },
            "dataset2":{
                "date": {...}
            }
        }
    },
    "something else": {
        ...
    },
    "something else": {
        ...
    }
};
var dataInRandomKey = response.data[Object.keys(response.data)[0]];
```

Now, you have the whole JSON object (in current example, response['data']['Random String that Changes']) in dataInRandomKey variable.

Comment: `response.data` is not a function

Comment: Edited. Now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
Consider sample data in myObj.

var myObj = {
    "data" : {
        "Random String that Changes": { 
          "dataset1": {
            "date": "123"
           },
          "dataset2":{
            "date": "123"
          }
        }
    }
  }


  var randomString =myObj[Object.keys(myObj)[0]];
  var dataset1Date =randomString[Object.keys(randomString)[0]].dataset1.date;
  console.log(dataset1Date);

So in this way you can access the date which you are trying with 
this.props.data.randomData['Random String that Changes'].dataset1.date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `for in` loop

```
var a = {
"data": {
    "Random String that Changes": { 
        "dataset1": {
            "date": {...}
        },
        "dataset2":{
            "date": {...}
        }
    }
},
"something else": {
    ...
},
"something else": {
   ...
}
}

var response = a.data;

for(var key in response) {
    console.log(response[key].dataset1);
}
```