# Firebase orderByChild - retrieve nested object

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a real-time database and have the following structure:

```
{
  "users": {
     "1234": {
       "name": "Joe",
       "externalId": "384738473847",
      },
      "5678": { ... },
      "5555": { ... }
  }
}
```

I now want to access a user via the `externalId` and I am using the following to access this object:

```
const snapshot = await admin.database().ref(`/users/`).orderByChild('externalId').equalTo(`${someId}`).once('value')
```

This will return me the following:

```
{
    "1234": {
        “name”:Joe,
        “externalId:”384738473847"
    }
}
```

I would now would like to access the object (containing the `name` and `externalId`) without knowing the id (which is 1234).

I currently have this solution:

```
const rootValue = Object.keys(userSnapshot.val())[0]
const user = userSnapshot.val()[rootValue]
```

Which works, but I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/how-to-access-the-first-property-of-a-javascript-object) that this is not the optimal way to do this. Is there a better way to access the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code needs to handle the list, and the best way is to use the built-in `Snapshot.forEach` operation:

```
const snapshot = await admin.database().ref(`/users/`).orderByChild('externalId').equalTo(`${someId}`).once('value')       
snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
  console.log(userSnapshot.key);
  console.log(userSnapshot.val());
  console.log(userSnapshot.val().name, userSnapshot.val().externalId);
});
```