# Get first enum item from an enum

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get the first item of an enum in typescript?

For example, `Option.All` in this enum:

```
enum Option {
    All = "all",
    Mine = "mine",
}
```

Tried, but won't compile:

```
const first: Option = Option[0]; // first should be All. This won't compile - Property '0' does not exist on type 'typeof Option'.
```

Comment: An enum becomes an object, which isn't an ordered data structure. There's only a 0th value if you let the compiler auto-number them from 0. But what's the context, why do you need the first value?

Comment: The enum code is generated and I need a default value.

Comment: What do you mean it's generated? If this isn't happening at compile time it's not really a TypeScript question, you're effectively asking https://stackoverflow.com/q/983267/3001761.

Comment: Well the generated code is Typescript, but out of my control. I can't change it, but need a (first) value. I could loop the enum, so there is an first in some sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option is essentially an Object.

This is how it is defined when compiled to JS:

```
var Option;
(function (Option) {
    Option["All"] = "all";
    Option["Mine"] = "mine";
})(Option || (Option = {}));
```

You can use Object.keys() or Object.values() to be able to convert an Object to an array.

Thus, in order to make first = 'All', you can use:

```
enum Option {
    All = "all",
    Mine = "mine",
}

const first = Object.keys(Option)[0];
console.log(first)
```

If you want to play around with how things look between TS and JS, you can use the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gDgFwJYHsRQN4FgBQV9QCCANsVALxQBEAhqVQDS4FQCySIwF1EHwjuAL65cAYzQBnBFABmSAE5TuMAEYArYKIQA6ANbAAnhIAU8ZGgCUAbQAMAXQDcYySmLBtxFAHNjcxQgsoAHogqAByEmIwkRxxECU-KQA1OjAuSlUNLW0AN1TgEzNUEGt7J1iXNw9vXwVk-MCQ8Loo3CA). I've loaded this link in with the code I showed here.

---

If you want the firstValue to be of type Option, use `Object.values(Option)[0]`.

Typescript playground seems to have an issue with the name `Option`, so if you change it to `Options`, it shows correctly that first is of type `Options`: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gDgFwJYHsQGcoG8CwAoKQqAQQBtSoBeKAIgENyaAafIqAWSRGCtoi+DN8AX3z4AxmnQIoAMyQAnabxgAjAFbBxCAHQA3BmGDoAFPGRSAlAG0ADAF0A3BKkpSwHaRQBzE-KUIllAA9MFQAOQMpOFQKLJQCACecDzmqBj4QA)

```
enum Options {
    All = "all",
    Mine = "mine",
}

const first = Object.values(Options)[0];
console.log(first) // 'all' of type Options
```

My local environment doesn't show that same weirdness.

Comment: `first` is here of type `string`, I need the Enum value. Maybe I should called it Enum item?

Comment: The 2nd playground link is broken?

Comment: I fixed the link. Not sure how that happened.

Comment: Excellent, this works: `const first: Options = Object.values(Options)[0];`

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
Option[Object.keys(Option)[0]]
```

Comment: That gives: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngeQA4BcCWB7EUDeAoKQqAQQBtSoBeKAIgENyaAaAomNEYK2iD4ZvAF88eAMZYAziigAzNACcpALliJUmbNXjJ0WANoIARgCtgolADoA1sDgSAFNvVYAlHoAMAXU9A)

Comment: @Julian You could write `Option[Object.keys(Option)[0] as keyof typeof Option]`