# fetch specifi data from json and store them in array using node js / Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I am trying to fetch all the log details from this json object but the problem is this key always get changed

```
let userJsonObject =
{
  "user_1":{
     "id":"user_1",
     "log":"de-data",
     "name":"dummy test",
     "address":"New York"
  },
  "user_2":{
     "id":"user_2",
     "log":"ex-file",
     "name":"tom",
     "address":"Nevada"
  },
  "user_3":{
     "id":"user_3",
     "log":"dis-acta",
     "name":"Jerry",
     "address":"LA"
  },
}
```

this is my json Object and I want fetch all the log which are present inside the json object and store them in one array like this

```
let gotLog= ["de-data","ex-file","dis-acta"]
```

here `user_1 user_2` get changed everytime and I wanted to tackle this scenario and fetch all the log in one array

Comment: user_1 changes to x name, and you don't know it? did I understood well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let userJsonObject =
{
  "user_1":{
     "id":"user_1",
     "log":"de-data",
     "name":"dummy test",
     "address":"New York"
  },
  "user_2":{
     "id":"user_2",
     "log":"ex-file",
     "name":"tom",
     "address":"Nevada"
  },
  "user_3":{
     "id":"user_3",
     "log":"dis-acta",
     "name":"Jerry",
     "address":"LA"
  },
};


let array=[];
for(const value of Object.values(userJsonObject)){
    array.push(value.log)
};
console.log(array);
```

I got it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal' };
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
```

I found this here [How to access the first property of a Javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/how-to-access-the-first-property-of-a-javascript-object)