# Get an array containing values of dynamic object property from the given array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an array like this-

```
[{a:23},{b:23},{r:2323},{e:99}]
```

I want to convert this to a new array containing only the object property values like-

```
[23,23,2323,99]
```

I have tried all the methods but could not figure out the way. Can anyone suggest me the idea for this please.

Comment: `arr.map((o) => Object.values(o)).flat();` or `arr.flatMap((o) => Object.values(o));` Though should should show what research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
const data = [{a:23}, {b:23}, {r:2323}, {e:99}];

const result = data.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: Can simply be data.flatMap(Object.values)

Comment: @makeitmorehuman That's a great point!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [ { a: 23 }, { b: 23 }, { r: 2323 }, { e: 99 } ]
let array1 = []

for (const obj of array) {
  array1.push(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]])
}

console.log(array1) // [23, 23, 2323, 99]
```

- `obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]` returns the first property of the object `obj` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509718))