# Object.keys() complexity?

Tags: javascript, performance, time-complexity, ecmascript-5

Anyone know the time-complexity of ECMAScript5's Object.keys() in common implementations?  Is it `O(n)` for `n` keys?  Is time proportional to the size of the hash table, assuming a hash implementation?

I'm looking for either guarantees by language implementors or some real world benchmarking.

Comment: How many keys do you expect to be having, such that the time complexity of enumerating them matters?

Comment: I don't think it can be less than `O(n)`

Comment: @PabloFernandez, length is less then O(n)

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory: While the function `Object.keys()` may be able to return in `O(1)`, *enumerating the results* can't be done in less than `O(n)`.

Comment: @Gabe, one million. Does that change the answer?

Comment: @Gabe Can you explain more about how Object.keys() may be able to return in O(1)?

Comment: @user137717, The Object implementation could _theoretically_ store an array of keys, changing the array whenever a new property is added or one is deleted. The keys function would then simply return the stored array. This has consequences on storage and offloads time spent in the keys function to time spent when creating and deleting keys.

Comment: Yea, that's what I thought. Doesn't really make sense for the general implementation, but a programmer could do it themselves pretty easily for their own use case.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It appears to be `O(n)` in V8 (chrome, node.js) at least:

```
> var hash = {}
>   ,    c = 0;
> 
> var s = +new Date();Object.keys(hash);console.log(+new Date() - s);
0
> for(var i=0; i<100000; i++, c++){ hash[c] = 1; }
> var s = +new Date();Object.keys(hash);console.log(+new Date() - s);
26
> for(var i=0; i<100000; i++, c++){ hash[c] = 1; }
> var s = +new Date();Object.keys(hash);console.log(+new Date() - s);
49
> for(var i=0; i<100000; i++, c++){ hash[c] = 1; }
> var s = +new Date();Object.keys(hash);console.log(+new Date() - s);
75
> for(var i=0; i<100000; i++, c++){ hash[c] = 1; }
> var s = +new Date();Object.keys(hash);console.log(+new Date() - s);
102
```

Comment: Those results make sense for a dense hash map.  Does performance degrade as keys get more sparse?

Comment: @hurrymaplelad - What?  All JS hash keys are strings.  This code effectively generates `{'1':1, '2':1, '3':1, ...}`  _sparse_ vs _dense_ keys don't make sense for hash implementations, only arrays.  And it really doesn't make any sense for an engine to ever implement a hash as an array since numerical indexes are generally rather rare.  Though if you want to test that for some reason, just change `c++` to `c+=Math.random()` which will give you totally un-associatable keys.

Comment: @cwolves: An `Array` object is just an object whose properties are expected to be whole numbers. Those aren't terribly rare, and there are certainly JS implementations that use arrays to back `Array` instances.

Comment: @cwolves: [expanded your test](http://jsfiddle.net/EGmPb/) to cover variations in magnitude of key size, and results look consistent.  You're correct, _sparse vs dense_ does not apply to your test.  I was looking for an example with low [load factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Load_factor), but that's independent of key choice.  Are JS Objects generally implemented as hashmaps?  If so, is performance `O(n+s)`, where `s` is the size of the hash table?

Comment: JS Objects are not implemented as hashmaps, rather as pairs of arrays (that is C arrays, not JS Array objects) http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/chrome/devtools/docs/memory-analysis-101.html#v8_specifics

Comment: @Gabe - Not exactly.  `Array`s inherit from `Object` and there's often both `dense` and `sparse` implementations under the hood for how those arrays are handled.  I'm saying it would be rare to have numerical indexes on a generic object (`{}`).

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - Um, Yeah that page says that but it can't be 100% accurate.  If it were, you wouldn't have a constant-time lookup on object keys which would be absurd.

Comment: @cwolves: You don't need constant-time lookup on object keys in cases where you can do the lookup once when you JIT compile the code. The compiler can then emit code for an array index rather than a hash lookup.

Comment: I just had a look at the V8 source code, and turns out they use something called [FixedArray](http://codesearch.google.com/#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/v8/src/heap.cc&type=cs&l=3981) to store the [object keys](http://codesearch.google.com/#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/v8/src/objects.cc&type=cs&l=4713). My C++ sucks badly, so I won't dig any deeper.

Comment: I love the results and discussion, but I don't know what this means. Is this fast or slow? @MarkKahn

Comment: @Frozenfrank -- it's as fast as possible

Comment: This seems to be the case for `Object.values` as well, in case anyone else is wondering.

Comment: It's not the case for string-named properties though, contrary to what has been discussed above. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Chart shows O(N) for a simple case in Chrome 87, Firefox 81, Safari 14 https://jsfiddle.net/9u5ohnmb/

Comment: seems O(1) until twenty entries in the hash map

Answer (score 58):

(V8 developer here.)

The answer by Mark Kahn is correct for sufficiently dense integer-keyed/"indexed" properties, where complexity of `Object.keys()` is indeed O(n).

While the JavaScript spec pretends that all object properties are string-keyed/"named", that's not how modern high-performance engines implement it. Internally there's a huge difference! Indexed properties are stored in an array (as long as they are dense enough), which gives generally *much* better performance than a `{'1': 1, ...}` dictionary would.

For objects with thousands of *named* properties, our implementation indeed uses a hash table (as the question guessed), and that means **complexity of `Object.keys()` is O(n log n)**. That's because a hash table (of course) stores entries in its own order. `Object.keys()` must return named properties in the order in which they were created though, which we store as additional metadata, so that means we must sort the keys after retrieving them from the hash table, which is an O(n log n) operation.

Named properties on most objects that occur in practice (up to about a thousand properties) are (usually) stored *in creation order* in a special kind of internal array, so they can be retrieved in O(n) and don't need to be sorted.

So the summary is really "it depends" :-)

Comment: Hmm, but the question here is that if I use an `Object.keys()` will it be an `O(n)` or something else? I didn't fully understand your answer... In naive terms, if I have a hash map as follows: `{a:1,b:2,...}` and I use `Object.keys()` for the same, will the time complexity be `O(n)` or something else? Also, what if we just want to get the keys and not sort them?

Comment: There is no way to get an object's keys without sorting them. And as I wrote, whether the complexity of `Object.keys()` is O(n) or something else depends on the specifics of your object (and, naturally, on the implementation details of the specific version of the specific JavaScript engine you happen to be running on). There are no guarantees.

Comment: the cutoff for this is 20, which you can verify using code from the other answer and using really small objects, but calling Object.keys many times

Comment: @DaveAnkin: if it were that simple, I would have said so. It's not that simple. And it changes over time/versions/implementations. It also usually doesn't matter: for most common cases, assuming that `Object.keys()` has linear complexity is reasonable (even though it won't be true in _all_ cases). Please be aware that "code from the other answer" only illustrates one particular case, not all possible scenarios.

Comment: @jmrk sure, and no benchmark is perfect (i added Math.random().toString(16).substring(2) in order to get longer keys), but for object<string, string> 20 seems like the cutoff that the original poster was asking for)

Comment: @jmrk thanks for working on v8 and your answer by the way, I'd be curious if you know more about that other cutoff i accidentally discovered.

Comment: I'm curious if Object.keys(bigObject).length would still be O(n) or is the js optimizer something that can be relied on to ensure this is O(1)

Comment: It's never O(1).

Comment: I'm pretty sure [Python has insertion-order dictionaries with O(n) iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6), so it's definitely possibloe.

Comment: @jmrk So I guess this means that for-in iteration is also O(n log n)?

Comment: @HansBrende Yes. `for-in` additionally has to walk the prototype chain, which (depending on how you define `n`) might not change asymptotic complexity but is generally more work.

Comment: @jmrk what if we know that the prototype is Object.prototype? Is that fast-tracked for for-in since the prototype chain is only length 1 and all properties are "own" properties? Would for-in be faster than Object.keys in that case since it avoids allocating the array?

Comment: @HansBrende `for-in` must always visit prototypes, and its fast path allocates an array under the hood. I doubt that it is ever faster than any alternative, but when in doubt, measure it yourself (using your full app or a _very_ realistic simulation of it, not just a simple microbenchmark).

Comment: @jmrk oh WOW, that is really counter-intuitive! Because that means that even if I wanted to extract only ONE property key from an object, the performance would still be O(n log n) due to that hidden array allocation. E.g., `for (let key in obj) return key` would still be O(n log n) rather than O(1) is what you're saying? 

Comment: Just a side question, are calls to `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` memoized? Would calling it multiple times result in constant times for subsequent calls if the values of the object haven't changed?

Comment: @AbirTaheer No, AFAIK they are not memoized. Presumably because it's too hard to estimate whether the memory consumption of memoization is worth it.

Comment: @jmrk I'm curious how this compares to the Standard built-in object "Map" and what performance would look like when using map to iterate, and add keys to a new array? Would this be strictly O(n)? (asking for node.js v16+)

Comment: @JattCode113 it's off-topic for this question, but if I'm reading the code right, iterating over a `Map` should be O(n) in our current implementation.