# Compare properties that exist in both objects

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

I have two objects:

```
var a = {
  world: 'Mamba',
  planet: 'Oliver'
}

var b = {
  world: 'Koko'
}
```

How do I compare only those properties that exists in both objects? On my example it would be the property "world".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using underscore:

You can get the keys of both objects (using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)), do an intersection (using [_.intersect](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection)) on them and iterate through them and compare:

```
var keys1 = Object.keys(a);
var keys2 = Object.keys(b);

var common = _.intersection(keys1, keys2);

common.forEach(function(key) {
    if(a[key] === b[key]) { 
       // they are equal 
    }
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var a = {
  world: 'Mamba',
  planet: 'Oliver',
  test: 'x'
};

var b = {
  world: 'Koko',
  test: 'x'
};

var keys1 = Object.keys(a);
var keys2 = Object.keys(b);

var common = _.intersection(keys1, keys2);

var list = document.getElementById('list');
common.forEach(function(c) {
  list.innerHTML += ('<li id=' + c + '>' + c + '</li>');
});

common.forEach(function(key) {

  var elem = document.getElementById(key);
  if (a[key] === b[key]) {
    elem.innerHTML += ' [equal]';
  } else {
     elem.innerHTML += ' [not equal]';  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<h3>Common Properties</h3>
<ul id="list">
  <ul>
```

### Using vanilla JS:

You can iterate over all properties of a, check if it exists in b, and compare:

```
for(var prop in a) {
    if(a.hasOwnProperty(prop) && b.hasOwnProperty(prop) && a[prop] === b[prop]) {
        // they are equal
    }
}
```

Note: Use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to not include properties available via prototype.

**DEMO**

```js
var a = {
  world: 'Mamba',
  planet: 'Oliver',
  test: 'x'
};

var b = {
  world: 'Koko',
  test: 'x'
};

var list = document.getElementById('list');
for (var prop in a) {
  
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(prop) && b.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  
    list.innerHTML += '<li id="' + prop + '">' + prop + '</li>';

    var elem = document.getElementById(prop);
    if (a[prop] === b[prop]) {
      elem.innerHTML += ' [equal]';
    } else {
      elem.innerHTML += ' [not equal]';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Common Properties</h3>
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

---

The vanilla JS way is **more efficient** in terms of run time.

The reason being that it only iterates over the properties of `a` once.

The underscore way needs to obtain object keys (which requires [iteration over each object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716812/object-keys-complexity)), then another iteration through the key arrays to find the intersection, and then iterate again over the intersection before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use underscore Js, it would be easy for you. Underscore has a method(_.intersection) which iterate over object or array.

```
 var intersection=_.intersection(keys(a),keys(b));
 console.log(intersection);  // ["world"]
 $.each(intersection,function(index,value){
   if(a[value] == b[value])
     //write your code
});
```

Otherwise firstly find intersection of objects and iterate the matched array for matching the related value.

```
var a = {
  world: 'Mamba',
  planet: 'Oliver'
}

var b = {
  world: 'Koko'
}
var arr = [];

// Find the matched keys in array(Intersection of keys)

$.each(Object.keys(a), function(index1, value1) {
  $.each(Object.keys(b), function(index2, value2) {
    if (value1 == value2)
      arr.push(value1)
  });

});

//Then iterate over array of keys to find matched value.

$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
  if (a[value] == b[value])
  // write your code.
});
```