# How to select nth item inside the object

Tags: javascript, json, object

Say if you were unable to access a certain item inside an object through dot notation like `objectName.objectItem` i.e. it has random name al the time. Is there a way to alternatively access it like second item?

how to get item2 from this object by only knowing that it is second item there?:

```
something: {
  item1: "text",
  item2: "text",
  item3: "text:,
  ...
}
```

Comment: order of keys are not fixed in javascript object

Comment: you can using Object.keys() ; but the order is not guaranteed to be what you expect;

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Order of keys are not fixed in javascript object.

You can try

```
var secondKey = Object.keys(something)[1]; //fetched the key at second index
alert(something[secondKey ]);
```

Comment: what is the time complexity of `Object.keys(something)[1];`?

Comment: O(n)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716812/object-keys-complexity

Answer (score 3):

Object keys have no order, but you can define your own binary relation that orders the keys.

Say, you only consider keys starting with `"item"` and a numeral suffix such as `item23`, then you can per your own **definition** translate this into the number `23` and decide that `item23` is the *23rd* item in your array.

Mind that this is completely arbitrary and only true in so far you want it to be so in your code.

That said, you can implement a function that filters all keys (considering only those starting with `"item"`), parse the numeral suffix into a number and then compare that to what index of an item you want.

This code does exactly what I've supposed you want to do:

```
function nth(obj, n)
{
  var key, i;

  for (key in obj)
  {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) // always do this when you scan an object
    {
      if (key.indexOf("item") === 0) // this is the filter
      {
        i = parseInt(key.substring(4), 10); // parse the numeral after "item"
        if (i === n)
        {
          return obj[key]; // return this value
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, with map...

```
something= new Map([ 
   [1, "text"],
   [2, "text"],
   [3, "text"]
])
something.get(nth)
```

Comment: u can convert your object to map--> myMap = new Map(Object.entries(obj));