# Get Children of JSON Elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

If I were to have a Json file that looked something like this:

```
{
  "numbers":{
     "firstnum":"one",
     "secondnum":"two",
     "thirdnum":"three",
     "fourthnum":"four",
     "fifthnum":"five"
  }
}
```

and I wanted to get the value of the third number (three) using JavaScript. Instead of doing...

```
jsonObject.numbers.thirdnum
```

Is there a way I can select that value using some sort of children or index method? for example something kind of like this...

```
jsonObject.numbers.children[2]
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+get+nth+key+of+object) of [How to select nth item inside the object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35722324/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to convert your JSON to JavaScript:

```
const object = JSON.parse(string_of_json);
```

Then you can get an array of an objects properties, keys, or both with the appropriate [methods on the `Object` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

```
Object.keys(object.numbers)[2];
Object.values(object.numbers)[2];
Object.entries(object.numbers)[2];
```

Since order isn't guaranteed, this isn't generally useful unless you want to do something to **every** item item you get back.

If you want to access them by position then you should usually write your orignal JSON to use an array instead of an object.

```
{
    "numbers": [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values` to convert the values to an array and attach the index.

```js
obj = {
  "numbers":{
     "firstnum":"one",
     "secondnum":"two",
     "thirdnum":"three",
     "fourthnum":"four",
     "fifthnum":"five"
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(obj.numbers)[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

After you parse JSON it became Object, so

```js
const obj = {
  "numbers": {
     "firstnum":"one",
     "secondnum":"two",
     "thirdnum":"three",
     "fourthnum":"four",
     "fifthnum":"five"
  }
};

console.log(obj.numbers[Object.keys(obj.numbers)[2]]);
```