# Time complexity of filter with a nested loop

Tags: javascript, filter, time-complexity, big-o

I'm fairly new to Big O and I am not sure what the time complexity of the following code will be:

```
const items = [
  {type: 'phone', name: 'iPhone', color: 'gold'},
  {type: 'phone', name: 'Samsung', color: 'gold'},
  {type: 'laptop', name: 'Chromebook', color: 'gray'},
  {type: 'tv', name: 'LG', color: 'gray'},
  {type: 'gooo', name: 'LG', color: 'silver'},
  {type: 'phone', name: 'Nokia', color: 'gold'}
];

items.filter(item => {
    for(let i=0; i < Object.keys(item).length; i++) {
        console.log('item is', Object.keys(item)[i])
    }
})
```

Can we say this is `O(i + c)` where `i` is `items` and `c` is the constant `console.log`? Or do we need to say something like `O(i * j + c)` where `j` is the individual `item` i.e. `{type: 'phone', name: 'iPhone', color: 'gold'}`

Can someone please help me out... thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to archive? Because your filter method is not really filtering anything

Comment: It's actually a little more complicated because of the way you are calling `Object.keys()` which itself has a complexity of O(n) (you are calling it once per iteration in the `for` condition and again in the console.log) see: [Object.keys() complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64912755/13762301)

Answer (score 1):

The `items.filter(() => { ... })` is a loop => `O(n)`.

You have a `for` loop inside of it looping over the object keys => `O(m * n)`.

The `Object.keys()` is `O(m)` in V8 and you have it twice in the `for` loop (in the condition so it's called in every iteration and in the loop body) so it's => `O(m ^ 2 * n)` (where `m` is the number of keys).

Also, you can use

```js
for (let key in item) {
  // and do whatever you want with the key
}
```

instead of using `Object.keys`.

Comment: The inner loop is not `n` it's `m` as it's the length of item.keys

Comment: Oh! sorry I missed that. thanks, @pilchard

Comment: Why `O(n^2)`? Doesn't the inner loop iterate over `m` keys in a single item and not over `n` items?

Comment: It should be `O(m ^ 2 * n)` where `m` is the number of keys.

Comment: Thank you for helping out its useful to know all this :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me change your code a bit:

```
items.filter(item => Object.keys(item).forEach(key => console.log("item is", key)));
```

The lambda is executed for every item in `items`. The lambda iterates over every key in an item and prints it. The time complexity is therefore O(n*m) for n = number of items and m = number of keys per item. If the number of keys per item is fixed and relatively small, you can assume O(n). The big O notation is just an rough estimate about the runtime, constant factors aren't that interesting.

Comment: You're missing the complexity of `Object.keys()`

Comment: When we say "relatively small", what does that roughly look like? as in where do we draw the line to consider O(n) (or not)? And yes also... as @pilchard mentions, do we consider `Object.keys()`?

Comment: I guess, that's negligible. Calling `Object.keys` has a complexity of O(m) and it is called once for every item. The `forEach` loop has a complexity of O(m) as well and is also called once for every item. The filter condition hence has a complexity of O(2m) = O(m).

Comment: @Mohammed It depends. In this example, I'd say, if the number of keys is constant (i.e., the items have a "schema"), but the number of items unbounded, then the number of keys is negligible. If, however, the number of keys is in practice unbounded (no fixed "schema"), then m should be considered as well.

Comment: Note: The reason I changed the code is that calling `Object.keys` within the inner loop body is unnecessary. It just needs to be called once per item, which reduces the complexity a lot (cf. Mahmoud's answer).

Comment: Yeah I think that makes sense. Thanks a lot I think I got my answer... it basically boils down to O(n*m) where n is items and m is no of keys per item :) (in your version of course)