# Randomly select enumerable property of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Given a dictionary-like object in Javascript such as `{a:1, b:-2, c:42}`, is there a simple way to randomly choose a property?

In the above example, I would like to have a function that would return `a`, `b` or `c` randomly.

The solution I've come up with is like the following:

```
    var proplist = []
    forEach(property in foo) {
        if(propertyIsEnumerable(foo[property]) {
            proplist.push(property);
        }
    }
    var n = proplist.length;
    // randomly choose property (randInt(n) returns a random integer in [0,n))
    proplist[randInt(n)];
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pick random property from a Javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532218/pick-random-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (or even [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)) to get a list of all properties. Then, select a random property by multiplying [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) with the length of the list, floored.

```
var propList = {}; //...
var tmpList = Object.keys(propList);
var randomPropertyName = tmpList[ Math.floor(Math.random()*tmpList.length) ];
var propertyValue = propList[randomPropertyName];
```

Comment: The `Object.keys` method is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This can be quite idiomatic with [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/):

```
 randomProp = _.shuffle(_.keys(obj))[0]
```

Edit: actually, one should use [`_.sample`](https://lodash.com/docs#sample) for that.

Comment: Of course this will involve shuffling the entire list of keys, with probably `n - 1` calls to `random`, where `n` is the length of `keys`.  As shown in another answer and the question, this is doable with only a single `random` call.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: of course, this is a wrong answer, edited.

Comment: @georg your link for `_.sample` points to lodash, not underscore, although the function is available in both

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to write a reusable function for this, you could do

```
const randomFrom = list => list[Math.floor(list.length * Math.random())];
const randomProp = obj => randomFrom(Object.keys(obj));

randomProp(propList); //=> one of the keys of propList
```

This will return `undefined` if your object has no properties, but that's probably the best we could do in any case.