# Is there a concept of "opposite HSL color"?

Tags: colors, hsl

I would like to have fields for which background color will be generated from their content (this will be in javascript but this does not matter I believe for my question).

I will therefore have, for instance, a background of `hsl(218, 52%, 83%)` (some kind of pale violet). This field will also have text in it, and I would like the text to have as much contrast as possible relative to the background.

**Is there a concept of "color opposite to a given HSL one"?**

Comment: I found a similar question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165107/how-do-i-invert-a-colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165107/how-do-i-invert-a-colour)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate Random Color distinguishable to Humans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10014271/11683)