# Chart.js Pie with best random background color

Tags: javascript, colors, chart.js, contrast

I have some data that will be visualized in Pie Chart form.

However, I want 2 adjacent colors not to be identical. For example, if I have 3 data then I don't want them to have the background colors `#90EE90`, `#A1FFA1`, and `#FF0000` because the colors `#90EE90` and `#A1FFA1` have a bad contrast score according to [coolors.co](https://coolors.co/contrast-checker/90ee90-a1ffa1).

```js
let randomColor = () => {
  let characters='0123456789ABCDEF';
  let randomString='';
  for (let i=0; i<6; i++) {
    let randomIndex=Math.floor(Math.random()*characters.length);
    randomString+=characters.charAt(randomIndex);
  }
  return '#'+randomString;
}
let round = (num) => Math.round(num*100)/100;

let chart = null;
$('#generate').click(()=>{
  let data = [];
  let labels = [];
  let pieces = $('#pieces').val();
  for(let i=0; i<pieces; i++) {
    labels.push(randomColor());
    data.push(round(1/pieces));
  }
  if(chart) chart.destroy();
  chart = new Chart($('#chart'), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: labels,
        borderWidth: 0
      }]
    },
    options: {
      plugins: {
        tooltip: {
          callbacks: {
            label: (context) => {
              return context.parsed;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="pieces" type="number" value="20" />
  <button id="generate">Generate Chart</button>
</div>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Can you help me generate some random background colors but adjacent colors have a good contrast score or don't hurt the eyes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a color-contrast checker library, like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wcag-contrast

It's based on the **WCAG contrast ratio** standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#contrast-ratiodef

Using the `hex()` function, you can check the contrast ratio between two hex values, which is a value between `1` (low contrast) and `21` (high contrast).

Your code can be improved in many different ways, anyway i only added the "core" improvements to add the discussed functionality (so you can better understand what i've done)

```js
const CONTRAST_THRESHOLD = 6;

let randomColor = (prevColor = '#fff') => {
    const characters='0123456789ABCDEF';
    let currentColor;
    do {
        currentColor = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            let randomIndex=Math.floor(Math.random()*characters.length);
            currentColor+=characters.charAt(randomIndex);
        }
    } while (wcagContrast.hex(prevColor, currentColor) < CONTRAST_THRESHOLD)

    return '#'+currentColor;
}

let checkFirstAndLastColor = (colorsArray) => {
    while (wcagContrast.hex(colorsArray[0], colorsArray[colorsArray.length -1]) < CONTRAST_THRESHOLD || wcagContrast.hex(colorsArray[0], colorsArray[1]) < CONTRAST_THRESHOLD) {
        colorsArray[0] = randomColor(colorsArray[1]);
    }
}

let round = (num) => Math.round(num*100)/100;

let chart = null;
$('#generate').click(()=>{
    let data = [];
    let labels = [];
    let pieces = $('#pieces').val();
    for(let i=0; i<pieces; i++) {
        labels.push(randomColor(labels[i - 1]));
        data.push(round(1/pieces));
    }
    if (labels.length > 2) {
        checkFirstAndLastColor(labels);
    }
    if(chart) chart.destroy();
    chart = new Chart($('#chart'), {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: labels,
                borderWidth: 0
            }]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: (context) => {
                            return context.parsed;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wcag-contrast@3.0.0/dist/index.umd.min.js
"></script>
<div>
  <input id="pieces" type="number" value="20" />
  <button id="generate">Generate Chart</button>
</div>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

The main idea is:

1. Upgrade the `randomColor()` function to check if `currentColor` has a high contrast with the previous color (`prevColor`). Otherwise, generate another color until contrast ratio is `>= CONTRAST_THRESHOLD` (set a number between 1 and 21).
2. Run `checkFirstAndLastColor` when all colors are set to check if the last color and the first one have an high contrast. If not, change the first color until it reach an high contrast with both the second and the last colors.

As already said, code could be improved in many ways, i hope my answer gives you the right hint to reach your result.

Comment: Thanks, @Alberto. However, this code gives an error when inputting an odd number.

Comment: Sorry, i'm going to fix it, i tested it quickly

Comment: Just checked, it's not a "real" code issue, it's more like a logic problem. If you set `CONTRAST_THRESHOLD` to 2 seems to work (and colors seems to be in contrast enough). Using a `> 3` value makes `checkFirstAndLastColor()` to infinite loop because he cannot find a color which is in high contrast both with the second and the last element of the array. It's normal: image a threshold of 21 (that is the max possible) in a 3-elements array: it's impossible to satisfy the rule. The solution here is to try with `CONTRAST_THRESHOLD=2` or totally remove `checkFirstAndLastColor` logic.

Comment: By removing `checkFirstAndLastColor`, the first and the last color could be low contrast.

Comment: does it mean I can't change the threshold greater than 2 or without checking `checkFirstAndLastColor`?

Comment: Now, it works 100% well for even numbers (and also for odd numbers if you keep `CONTRAST_THRESHOLD=2`). If you remove `checkFirstAndLastColor` it works well also with odd numbers, but the last 2 slices may be in low contrast.

Imagine a situation where you have only black and white. If you have an even number of slices, it works well (last 2 slices will be always of different colors). But, if you use an odd number, it would never work (last two slices will always be of the same color). This is why you have to implement your own logic about this.

Comment: There's no official/better solution, it depends on your needs.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll try to implement some logic for the last two slices if use an odd number. Thanks @Alberto

Answer (score 1):

```js
const CONTRAST_THRESHOLD = 4.5;
let generatedColors = new Set();

let randomColor = () => {
    let currentColor;
    let contrastIsOk;
    // Generate a random color and ensure it has a high enough contrast ratio with all previously generated colors
    do {
        currentColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16).padEnd(6, '0');
        contrastIsOk = [...generatedColors].every(col => wcagContrast.hex(col, currentColor) >= CONTRAST_THRESHOLD);
    } while (generatedColors.has(currentColor) || !contrastIsOk);
    
    generatedColors.add(currentColor);
    return currentColor;
}

let round = (num) => Math.round(num * 100) / 100;

let chart = null;
$('#generate').click(() => {
    let data = [];
    let colors = [];
    generatedColors.clear();
    let pieces = $('#pieces').val();

    // Generate a unique color for each piece of the pie chart
    for (let i = 0; i < pieces; i++) {
        colors.push(randomColor());
        data.push(round(1 / pieces));
    }

    // Special handling for odd numbers of pieces to avoid low contrast between the first and last segments
    if (pieces % 2 !== 0 && wcagContrast.hex(colors[0], colors[colors.length - 1]) < CONTRAST_THRESHOLD) {
        // Re-generate the last color to ensure contrast
        let lastColor;
        do {
            lastColor = randomColor();
        } while (wcagContrast.hex(colors[0], lastColor) < CONTRAST_THRESHOLD);
        colors[colors.length - 1] = lastColor;
    }

    if (chart) chart.destroy();

    // Create the pie chart with the generated colors
    chart = new Chart($('#chart'), {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: colors.map((color, index) => `Color ${index + 1}`), // Label each color for clarity
            datasets: [{
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: colors,
                borderWidth: 0
            }]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: (context) => `${context.label}: ${context.parsed}`
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And ensure to include the WCAG contrast library:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wcag-contrast@3.0.0/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7pqI.png - Still get a identical background color btw

Comment: I have updated the source code. Can you please try it again?

Comment: Still get a problem for odd pieces : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb9VW.png

Comment: I've updated my response with new code.

Answer (score 1):

There is plugin called chroma js which can help
a lot to work with colors https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/

Edit:

- Now it check also with if first and last have contrast
- regeneratColorIteration can be changed to any positive number to change starting color
- minContrast now is more external to configurate minimal contrast of coresponding chart parts
- check if exact color isn't already used in another chart part

Code utilize answers of

- @user1537366 from [Generate Random Color distinguishable to Humans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014271/generate-random-color-distinguishable-to-humans)
- @icl7126 from [RGB to hex and hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

```js
let minContrast = 2;

let randomByHsl = (colorNum) =>
{
    let hues = [0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 120, 160, 190, 210, 230, 260, 290, 330, 360];
    //hues = [...Array(37).keys()].map(x=>x*10);
    let lights = [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 43, 45, 48, 50, 53, 55, 58, 60, 63, 65, 68, 70, 73, 75, 80];
    let goldenFrac = 0.5 * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
    let x = (colorNum * goldenFrac % 1.0) * (hues.length - 1);
    //x=colorNum%(hues.length-1); // for point visualisation
    let i = Math.floor(x);
    let f = x % 1.0;
    let hue = (1.0 - f) * hues[i] + f * hues[i + 1];
    let light = (1.0 - f) * lights[i] + f * lights[i + 1];
    return [Math.round(hue * 100) / 100, 100, Math.round(light * 100) / 100];
}

let hslToHex = (h, s, l) =>
{
  l /= 100;
  s /= 100;

  const a = s * Math.min(l, 1 - l);
  const f = (n, h, l, a) => {
    const k = (n + h / 30) % 12;
    const color = l - a * Math.max(Math.min(k - 3, 9 - k, 1), -1);
    return Math.round(255 * color).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  };

  const red = f(0, h, l, a);
  const green = f(8, h, l, a);
  const blue = f(4, h, l, a);

  return `#${red}${green}${blue}`;
}

let makeColor = (colorNum) =>
{
  let newColor = randomByHsl(colorNum);
  return hslToHex(...newColor);
}

let calculateContrast = (color1, color2) =>
{
  return chroma.contrast(color1, color2);
}

let contrastCheck = (color, toCompare) =>
{
  if(toCompare.length)
  {
    let contrasts = [];

    toCompare.forEach((colorToCompare) =>
    {
      contrasts.push(calculateContrast(color, colorToCompare));
    });

    return contrasts.every(contrast => contrast > minContrast);
  }
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
}

let generateColors = (pieces) =>
{
  let labels = [];
  let data = [];
  let previousColor = null;
  let regeneratColorIteration = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < pieces; i++)
  {
    regeneratColorIteration++;

    let newColor = makeColor(regeneratColorIteration);
    let colorsToCompare = [];

    if(previousColor)
    {
      colorsToCompare.push(previousColor);
    }

    if(i == pieces - 1
    && i != 0)
    {
      colorsToCompare.push(labels[0]);
    }

    while(labels.includes(newColor)
    && ! contrastCheck(newColor, colorsToCompare))
    {
        regeneratColorIteration++;
        newColor = makeColor(regeneratColorIteration);
    }

    labels.push(newColor);
    data.push(round(1 / pieces));
    previousColor = newColor;
  }

  return { labels, data };
}

let round = (num) => Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
let chart = null;

$('#generate').click(() =>
{
    let pieces = $('#pieces').val();

    if(chart)
    {
        chart.destroy();
    }

    const { labels, data } = generateColors(pieces);

    chart = new Chart($('#chart'),
    {
        type: 'pie',
        data:
        {
            labels: labels,
            datasets:
            [{
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: labels,
                borderWidth: 0
            }]
        },
        options:
        {
            plugins:
            {
                tooltip:
                {
                    callbacks:
                    {
                        label: (context) => 
                        {
                            return context.parsed;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chroma-js/2.1.1/chroma.min.js"></script>

        <div>
          <input id="pieces" type="number" value="20" />
          <button id="generate">Generate Chart</button>
        </div>
        <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/77HUC.png, still get identic color for first and last pieces

Comment: I did some improvments check'up @Jordy