# How can I get one property name in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pick random property from a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532218/pick-random-property-from-a-javascript-object)

suppose I have a javascript object:

```
Config.UI.Area = {
        "uuid": {
            "_type": "string"
        },
        "frame": {
            "_type": "rect"
        },
        "zIndex": {
            "_type": "string"
        }
 }
```

then I want get each of the property's name,like "uuid","frame","zIndex"
by using for loop:

```
var prop=config.ui.area;
var arr=new Array()
for(var i in prop){
    //do something with prop[i]?
    //arr.push(prop[i].....)?
}
```

I can not directly use prop[i],it would return me an object,how can I just get it's name?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would give you an array of property *names*:

```
for(var name in prop){
    //do something with prop[name]?
    arr.push(name);
}
```

It would also give you the names of 'native' properties of the Object object. To avoid that, use the `hasOwnProperty` method:

```
for(var name in prop){
    if (prop.hasOwnPropery(name) {
     arr.push(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is how you iterate property and get corresponding value

```
var prop=config.ui.area;
var arr=new Array()
for(var i in prop){
    //do something with prop[i]?
    var propertyName = i;
    var propertyValue = prop[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

prop (and Config.UI.Area) is an object ( not an array of object ).
So you cannot do prop[i].

Try this,

```
   var obj = {
           "uuid": {
               "_type": "string"
           },
           "frame": {
               "_type": "rect"
           },
           "zIndex": {
               "_type": "string"
           }
    }

   var prop = obj;
   var arr=[];
   for(var i in prop){
       if(i.hasOwnProperty){
         arr.push(i);
       }
   }
   console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to the name of an object's property in a loop use:

```
for(var propertyName in myObject) {
  if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) {
    console.log(propertyName); // will be uuid, frame or zIndex
  }
}
```

To get to properties of the sub objects, use

```
for(var propertyName in myObject) {
  if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) {
    var subObject = myObject[propertyName];
    console.log(subObject._type);
           // will string or rect based on your sample code
  }
}
```

Using the `hasOwnProperty` in a loop through an object is a good idea as it will filter out properties of the object that are inherited via its `prototype`.