# Slash in if-statement JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm referring to this question: [Pick random property from a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532218/pick-random-property-from-a-javascript-object)

In the marked answer, the author is using the following code:

```
if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
       result = prop;
```

My questions:

1. What exactly is the function of the slash?
2. Is there a name for this syntax?

Thank you!

Comment: the slash divides the left by the right. it's called division.

Comment: / is usually division? Maybe put a space for clarity `1 / ++count`

Comment: arithmetic operations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a division :) Here's a few more parentheses to show what's going on:

```
if (Math.random() < (1) / (++count) )
    result = prop;
```

The `++count` operator means "increment the value of count, save it as count, and then return  it". `count++` means "return the value of count, then increment and save it as count":

```
val count = 0
val b = ++count //increment count, then set b to count (so b=1, count=1)
val c = count++ // set c to count and then increment count (so c=1, count=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simple division.
That is same as

```
var comparator = 1/++count;
if (Math.random() < comparator)
       result = prop;
```

Don't think `/` is doing some magic here.