# Pick random property and value from Javascript object

Tags: javascript, html

I've just started learning Javascript and need some help.

I wanted to build a random picker from an array which I accomplished

```
var movie = ["star wars", "lotr", "moonlight", "avengers"]

function newMovie() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (movie.length));

  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "You should watch " + movie[randomNumber];
}
```

Now I want to add more options for such as books, games.. so I've created an object for it:

```
var chooseOption = {
    watch: ["star wars", "lotr", "moonlight", "avengers"],
    read: ["scott pilgrim", "harry potter", "eragon"],
    play: ["starbound", "skyrim", "bioshock", "fallout"]
}
```

I'm a bit lost on how to proceed - I want it to first pick out one of the properties and then one of the values of the said property, all by random.
And then print it out in a `"You should" + [property] + [value]`

How would I do that? Is the object a way to go, or any better options?

Comment: Get a random number between 0 and chooseOption.length then do  chooseOption.key(random number);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick random property from a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2532218/90527)

Answer (score 2):

So, start by writing a generic pick function that takes an array and returns an item. I'll leave the implementation of that to you.

Next you need to use `Object.keys` to get an array like `['watch', 'read', 'play']`.

```
var chooseOption = {
    watch: ["star wars", "lotr", "moonlight", "avengers"],
    read: ["scott pilgrim", "harry potter", "eragon"],
    play: ["starbound", "skyrim", "bioshock", "fallout"]
}
var keys = Object.keys(chooseOption);
var type = pick(keys);
```

Then you can get the inner array by accessing the property by that key.

```
var items = chooseOption[type];
var item = pick(items);
```

And finally, display the result.

```
console.log('You should ' + type + ' ' + item);
```

Comment: Just a note: using Object.keys(chooseOption); doesn't guarantee the order in which the keys are returned. If order is important, you should base your chooseOption on an array instead of an object.

Comment: @Lys I would assume that order is not important here because the whole point is to select a property at random.

Comment: I agree, however I though it might be nice to mention it, just so @Timmster is aware, that there will be combination between the two random factors of random index and random order.

Comment: @Lys the order is guaranteed to be insertion order. There was a time where it wasn't in the spec, but all popular engines did this, so they added it.

Comment: I would say the kid was asking for the Pick function.. lol

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `Math.random()` to achieve randomness:

```
var chooseOption = {
    watch: ["star wars", "lotr", "moonlight", "avengers"],
    read: ["scott pilgrim", "harry potter", "eragon"],
    play: ["starbound", "skyrim", "bioshock", "fallout"]
}


function getRandom(obj, item){
  // 1) select which property to operate on.
  var itemArr = obj[item];

  // 2) we already know that the key can only be an integer(between 0 and length -1 )

  // Math.random()   : to generate a random number(between [0-1]).
  // Math.round()    : to round a number to an integer.
  // number % length : to make sure the result would be an integer between 0 and length -1 
  var index = Math.round((Math.random() * itemArr.length)) % itemArr.length;


  return {
    property:itemArr,
    index: index,
    value: itemArr[index],
  }

}


console.log(getRandom(chooseOption,'watch'));
console.log(getRandom(chooseOption,'read'));
console.log(getRandom(chooseOption,'play'));
```

Answer (score 1):

use with **`object.keys()`** and `Math.random()`

> 1. first select the random key from object using `Object.keys().length`.
> 2. Then get the respected array of the key.
> 3. Then pick the random value from the array using array length

```js
function newMovie() {
var types =Object.keys(chooseOption);
  var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * (types.length));
var t = types[rn];
var val = chooseOption[types[rn]];
var vn = Math.floor(Math.random() * (val.length));
var v = val[vn]
 console.log("You should watch " +t +' '+v);
}

var chooseOption = {
  watch: ["star wars", "lotr", "moonlight", "avengers"],
  read: ["scott pilgrim", "harry potter", "eragon"],
  play: ["starbound", "skyrim", "bioshock", "fallout"]
}
newMovie()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go,

```
    var options = {
        watch: ["star wars", "lotr", "moonlight", "avengers"],
        read: ["scott pilgrim", "harry potter", "eragon"],
        play: ["starbound", "skyrim", "bioshock", "fallout"]
    };

    for( i in options){
        //i is will be iterating with values "watch","read","play"
        t = Math.floor( Math.random()* options[i].length);
        //options[i] is to access the value of property eg: options["watch"]
        //will return ["star wars", "lotr", "moonlight", "avengers"]
        console.log("You should " + i +" "+ options[i][t]);
    }
```

Instead logging to something else with the code :)

Comment: the for loop is not random