# How does this algorithm to pick a random object key work? (Math.random() < 1/++c)

Tags: javascript

```
function randomKey(obj) {
    var ret;
    var c = 0;
    for (var key in obj)
        if (Math.random() < 1/++c)
           ret = key;
    return ret;
}
```

Can someone please explain how this code fairly picks a random key from the object?

Comment: We are probably passing a hash in randomKey function as obj, then we initialize two variables then a loop begins which will check whether a random num generated is smaller than 1/++c and then finally function returns the ret

Comment: never trust code that labels variables "ret" and "c"

Comment: @deceze You'd have a 1/20 chance of picking the 20th key (or any key) in a collection of 20 objects.

Comment: @Bill Yes, I realise that, still wondering the same as James whether the way this is iterated won't favour earlier keys. Probably just our intuition betraying us.

Comment: @deceze Yes, it definitely looks off. I had to step through it to be sure, but all the probabilities add up, so it has a sort of leveling effect.

Comment: actually yes I'm still inclined to think it's weighted - you only get the pick the first key once.  Then there's keys.length-1 chances of picking another, even if the chances of doing so are "balanced"

Comment: I'm inclined to post this on https://stats.stackexchange.com, but I'm scared and I won't understand the answers anyway. ;)

Comment: @deceze Yeah the thought had crossed my mind too :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe But there's a 100% chance that you pick that first key the first time, and all the other probabilities never add up to 1, so there will always be a chance that you just leave your first pick alone.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Right.  I never liked probabilities...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have three keys in `obj`. On the first iteration of the loop, `1/++c` will be `1`, so `ret` will always be set to the first key. In the second iteration, `1/++c` will equal 0.5, so there's a 1/2 probability that the random number generated will be less than that, so a 50% chance that you'll change `ret` to the second key. On the third iteration `1/++c` will be 0.333..., so there will be a 1/3 probability that `ret` will change to the third key.

For any size collection in `obj`, you should end up with an even distribution of keys.

Comment: @JamesThorpe This code looks like it might have come from an obfuscation competition.

Comment: Yeah, i agree it results in an even distribution. Strange way to do it though. I would just do a random int between 0 and Object.keys(obj).length -1 (assuming you only want own properties)

Comment: @NicholasTower This might be someone's job security. ;)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard what is the simplest and more efficient way to get random keys from an object?

Comment: @JohnAnisere The method Nicholas mentioned would be more straightforward than using a loop. There are several implementations on [Pick random property from a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2532218/1288), including the one you give in the question here. The second answer there is a simpler approach.

Comment: @BilltheLizard what does this `[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]` do?  I'm confused with use of the left shift bitwise operator

Comment: @JohnAnisere `keys.length * Math.random()` results in a float. Shifting 0 bits just converts it to an integer. JavaScript... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯