# What does the bitwise shift left accomplish here?

Tags: javascript

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15106541/10757573

In this thread, the solution uses the following code:

```
var randomProperty = function (obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj)
    return obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
};
```

In the comments from the answer, one user explained the bitwise shift as:

> It's more as a shorthand of `parseInt(keys.length * Math.random(), 0)`

---

Can anyone explain how the bitwise shift left 0 is the same as parseInt, or how it works in general, please?

I'm using this syntax, and it works well, but I don't understand what it's doing.

Comment: "*I'm using this syntax, and it works well, but I don't understand what it's doing.*" then how do you know it works *well*?

Comment: Also, `parseInt(keys.length * Math.random(), 0)` makes no sense - you parse the value into base zero? What is any number in base zero represented as?

Comment: @VLAZ `radix: 0` actually has special behaviour: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing `value << 0` in JavaScript has the effect of coercing `value` into an integer when `value` is a non-integer. This is needed in this case because `Math.random()` returns a floating-point number, which cannot be used as an integer indexer (`keys` is an `Array` so it's indexed by an integer).

`parseInt( /*string:*/ textValue, /*radix:*/ 0 )`  does not convert a number to "base 0", instead when `radix == 0`, the `parseInt` function will parse `textValue` as base 10 unless `textValue` starts with `0x` in which case it will parse it as base 16.

Answer (score 2):

The usual idiom for selecting a random array element is

```
array[Math.floor(array.length * Math.random())]
```

What this code is doing is using `<< 0` as a shortcut for `Math.floor()`. `keys.length * Math.random()` will be a floating point number. The `<<` operator requires that its operands be integers, so it will automatically convert that float to an integer, and it does this by rounding down, just like `Math.floor()` does.