# how to get different property from object?

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have this function:

```
getNewColor(): {} {
    return colors.red;
}
```

And this object:

```
colors: any = {
  red: {primary: '#ad2121',secondary: '#FAE3E3'},
  blue: {primary: '#1e90ff',secondary: '#D1E8FF'},
  yellow: {primary: '#e3bc08',secondary: '#FDF1BA'}
};
```

Every time `getNewColor()` is being called, a new color from the object should be returned (doesn't matter what color as long it's hasn't been returned before).

If I call:

```
console.log(getNewColor());
console.log(getNewColor());
console.log(getNewColor());
```

The output should be:

```
{primary: '#ad2121',secondary: '#FAE3E3'}
{primary: '#e3bc08',secondary: '#FDF1BA'}
{primary: '#1e90ff',secondary: '#D1E8FF'}
```

What is the best way to implement `getNewColor()`?

Comment: `getNewColor(color: string): any { return colors[color] }`? And you could use it as `getNewColor('red')`, `getNewColor('blue')` and `getNewColor('yellow')`. Or do you want to return a random color every time the function is called?

Comment: What do you mean: the order does not matter?
Maybe you meant: the color does not matter?

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes, this is what i meant.

Comment: @MichaelD this might not work, since i don't know the colors in my object, all I know is that I need it to give me some color it didn't gave before.

Comment: @HilaGrossbard: So you want to randomly return a color object from the function?

Comment: Your question lacks an attempt of what you're trying to do aswell as clarification whether the color should be random or/and should `never` return the same color.

Comment: @MichaelD  exactly, random and different.

Comment: Random property from an object is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2532218/6513921. But the _"different"_ needs further clarification. How and relative to which context is it supposed to be different? What if the function is called from different places, should each get exclusive responses?

Comment: If it's random and different, what should happen on the 4th call to the function?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli the times the function getNewColor() is being asked cant be bigger than the amount of colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```js
colors = {
  red: {primary: '#ad2121',secondary: '#FAE3E3'},
  blue: {primary: '#1e90ff',secondary: '#D1E8FF'},
  yellow: {primary: '#e3bc08',secondary: '#FDF1BA'}
};

const getColor=()=>{
    const keys = Object.keys(colors);
    const key = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length);
    return colors[keys[key]]
}
```

But I agree, that your question lacks of any attempts