# Take random array in a 2D named Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, 2d

I'd like to take a random array from a 2D named array but all solution I tried didn't work maybe someone could help

```
var sites = [];

sites['apple'] = [
'green'
,
'red'
,
'blue'
];

sites['orange'] = [
'yellow'
];
```

There is more and of course not these names and the number is not fix and I'd like to take one random array. (Not item !)

Is it possible ?

Comment: Arrays don't use string keys, if that's the structure you want you should use a regular object for the outer "array" instead.

Comment: You are supposed to show what you have tried to do, and we ar supposed to help you to make your code better, not to give you a free code

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yeah perfectly what I desired thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is :

```
var sites = [];

sites['apple'] = [
'green'
,
'red'
,
'blue'
];

sites['orange'] = [
'yellow'
];

var s_Array = Object.keys(sites);
var randomNumber = Math.random();
var s_Index  = Math.floor(randomNumber * s_Array.length);
var randomKey = s_Array[s_Index];
var randomsiteskey = sites[randomKey];
```

Check [Pick random property from a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532218/pick-random-property-from-a-javascript-object) as @John Montgomery mentionned it