# Get a random property from a TypeScript object:

Tags: typescript, object

I'm trying to make a function that takes an object as an argument and returns a random property of the object. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532218/pick-random-property-from-a-javascript-object) provides an answer- but Typescript doesn't like that I'm using a string to index an object.

```
    const randomElement = (obj: object) => {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return obj[keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
  
    }
```

In my project this function will always accept the same type of object (so I could use an interface), but I want to know if it's possible to make the function more flexible.

As requested here is my TS config file:

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src", "vite.config.ts"]
  }
```

The above code produces the following errors:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)
```

Comment: If I look at that code [in an IDE](https://tsplay.dev/mAj3vW) the only problem I see is that you haven't given a type to `obj`, so it's implicitly `any`, and that can be fixed by annotating it as `any` explicitly.  So your issue "doesn't like that I'm using a string to index an object" is not reproducible.  Could you provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates your problem?

Comment: please share also your tsconfig

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w160AN) meet your needs?

Comment: It does. For anyone else looking for the answer this is it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting it into number like this

```
Number(keys.length * Math.random() << 0)
```

You also can type your obj as follows

```
function (obj: [key: string]: any)
```

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: that works, but it doesn't let you use the useful features of Typescript because of the any time in the args

Comment: you can aslo type obj as I did in my answer

Comment: keys will be of type string, Number(keys.length * Math.random is number << 0) is garenteed to be of type number

Comment: Which feature of typescript are you looking for ?