# How I am supposed to get a random string output from an object in JS?

Tags: javascript, string, object, math, random

I need help with the following problem: How is it possible to extract a random value from the object below?

```
const hellos = {
English: "Hello",
Japanese: "Konnichiwa",
German: "Hallo",
Spanish: "Hola",
Arabic: "Ahlan wa sahlan",
Chinese: "Nihao",
};
```

random output in console to test. E.g. "konnichiawa", "hola", etc.

I couldn't write my code down, because it's still hard for me as a beginner in JS. Please kindly give me some tips. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/15106541/13583510 which picks a random key and return the value.
Since the key doesn't seem to be important as you haven't mentioned in your case you can choose a random value from the values array of the Object (`Object.values(hellos)`).
The answer in the link gives access to both the key and value so you can use it as well since retrieving a value from a given random key can be achieved in constant time.

```js
const hellos = {English: "Hello",Japanese: "Konnichiwa",German: "Hallo",Spanish: "Hola",Arabic: "Ahlan wa sahlan",Chinese: "Nihao",};

var randomVal = function (obj) {
    var vals = Object.values(obj);
    return vals[ vals.length * Math.random() << 0];
};

console.log(randomVal(hellos))
```

Comment: Does the bit operator `<<` shift `.length` to `.length-1`?

Comment: Does a Math.floor since the multiplication can give float

Comment: @cmgchess Could you please tell me why [vals.length * Math.random() << 0] ? why  <<0, not 0 << X < 1 ?

Comment: This is not less than 0 symbol. It means left shift . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift