# Select random value from a randomly selected array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm an absolute novice when it comes to Javascript and Jquery. I'm trying to develop a system that will select a set number from an array.

I've got 3 arrays and a system that will select one of the numbers from these arrays.

```
var selectedArray = ["sixMatched","fiveMatched","fourMatched","threeMatched"];

    var sixMatched = ["367687"];

    var fiveMatched = ["567687","337687","167687","367587","368687"];

    var fourMatched = ["387087","357187","365627","367620","369627","867987","367610","367604","394687","397681","367247","167683","767697","567617","367207"];

    var threeMatched = ["338680","965647","163637","333677","837637","267427","364288","357634","767817","361557","302682","667027","320637","547686","967088","382637","360167","327286","817187","707087","387481","357280","563287","367803","867646","277686","384697","364483","467827","332681"];
```

I'm using the math.random function to select a random array name via the selectedArray array.

I want to then use the name picked from selectedArray and use that to select a random value from either sixMatched, fiveMatched, etc.

```
    $('#play').click(function(){
        var winningArray = selectedArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*selectedArray.length)];
        var winningNumber = winningArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*winningArray.length)];
        
        $('#number').animateNumber({ number: (winningNumber)});
        console.log("Winning array is "+ winningArray +"");
        console.log("Winning number is "+ winningNumber +"");
        return false;   
    });
```

What my code is doing though is selecting a random letter from winningArray rather than treating the value of the variable as a variable selector to then.

I was hoping that since winningArray would be set to for example "sixMatched" the code would select the sixMatched array and select a random value from it, but instead it's selecting a random letter from the value of winningArray instead.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Note that the chances of picking `367687` from `sixMatched` are substantially higher than `338680` from `threeMatched`. This is probably by design, but just wanted to point it out in case you aren't aware. For example consider array A `[1]` and B `[2,3]`. If I first pick a random array each array has a 50% chance. If I then pick a random number from the array you combine the chances. Meaning that I have a 50% chance to pick `1` (0.5 * 1), but `2` and `3` both have 25% chance of being picked (0.5 * 0.5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of separate top-level variables, make the arrays properties on an object:

```
var matchedArrays = {
  sixMatched: ["367687"],
  fiveMatched: ["567687","337687","167687","367587","368687"],
  fourMatched: ["387087","357187","365627","367620","369627","867987","367610","367604","394687","397681","367247","167683","767697","567617","367207"],
  threeMatched: ["338680","965647","163637","333677","837637","267427","364288","357634","767817","361557","302682","667027","320637","547686","967088","382637","360167","327286","817187","707087","387481","357280","563287","367803","867646","277686","384697","364483","467827","332681"]
};
```

Then you can use your randomly selected string value to reference the property on that object:

```
var winningNumber = matchedArrays[winningArray][Math.floor(Math.random()*matchedArrays[winningArray].length)];
```

Notice that the reference to `winningArray` was replaced with `matchedArrays[winningArray]`, since `winningArray` itself is a string value and you can use strings to index object properties in JavaScript.

---

As an academic exercise at this point, you can get rid of the explicit `selectedArray` entirely and [dynamically use the list of properties on the `matchedArrays` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/208016/328193), so you don't need to manually keep the two synchronized if they ever change.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a random index of the string from `selectedArray`, not what you're looking for.

---

Consider using an Object with keys and values, then you just need to [pick a random key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532218/pick-random-property-from-a-javascript-object) for the 'array name'.

Since it's an object, you can easily target it's key's value to get the array, then [get a random item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array) from that array:

```js
const allArrays = {
    sixMatched:  ["367687"],
    fiveMatched: ["567687","337687","167687","367587","368687"],
    fourMatched: ["387087","357187","365627","367620","369627","867987","367610","367604","394687","397681","367247","167683","767697","567617","367207"],
    threeMatched:["338680","965647","163637","333677","837637","267427","364288","357634","767817","361557","302682","667027","320637","547686","967088","382637","360167","327286","817187","707087","387481","357280","563287","367803","867646","277686","384697","364483","467827","332681"]
}

const allArrayKeys = Object.keys(allArrays);

var randomArrayKey = allArrayKeys[Math.floor(Math.random()*allArrayKeys.length)];
var randomArray    = allArrays[randomArrayKey]
var winningNumber = randomArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomArray.length)];

console.log("Winning array is "+ randomArrayKey +"");
console.log("Winning number is "+ winningNumber +"");
```