# Ordered hash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

JavaScript objects have no order stored for properties (according to the spec).  Firefox seems to preserve the order of definition of properties when using a `for...in` loop.  Is this behaviour something that I can rely on?  If not is there a piece of JavaScript code somewhere that implements an ordered hash type?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-for-in-loop-in-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question come up as the top search result. After not finding a ordered hash, i just wrote this small coffescript. Hopefully this will help folks landing on this page:

```
## OrderedHash
# f = new OrderedHash
# f.push('a', 1)
# f.keys()
# 
class OrderedHash
 constructor: ->
   @m_keys = []
   @m_vals = {}

  push: (k,v) ->
    if not @m_vals[k]
      @m_keys.push k
    @m_vals[k] = v

  length: () -> return @m_keys.length

  keys: () -> return @m_keys

  val: (k) -> return @m_vals[k]
  vals: () -> return @m_vals
```

Comment: OP asked for a solution in JavaScript -> see below for my port

Comment: @FloLedermann Thanks, also, http://js2.coffee/ can help in these situations generally.

Comment: `if not @m_vals[k]` seems like it would push the key to the m_keys array again if the value is anything falsy. Should probably do a `if (!(k in this.m_vals))` (writing it that way because I don't know CoffeeScript).

Answer (score 66):

JavaScript in 2016, specifically EcmaScript 6, supports the [`Map` built-in class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

> A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order — a for...of loop returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.

That's what you need. (I wonder why that is the first info in the description of this data structure, though.)

For example,

```
m = new Map()

m.set(3,'three')
m.set(1,'one')
m.set(2,'two')

m // Map { 3 => 'three', 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two' }

[...m.keys()] // [ 3, 1, 2 ]
```

or the example from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Iterating_Maps_with_for..of):

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, 'zero');
myMap.set(1, 'one');

myMap // Map { 0 => 'zero', 1 => 'one' }

for (var [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}

for (var key of myMap.keys()) {
  console.log(key);
}

for (var value of myMap.values()) {
  console.log(value);
}

for (var [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
```

Comment: Important footnote - "Note that in the ECMAScript 2015 spec objects do preserve creation order for string and Symbol keys, so traversal of an object with only string keys would yield the keys in order of insertion"

Answer (score 25):

@Vardhan 's answer in plain JavaScript, using closure instead of classical OO and adding an insert() method:

```
function makeOrderedHash() {
    let keys = [];
    let vals = {};
    return {
        push: function(k,v) {
            if (!Object.hasOwn(vals,k)) keys.push(k);
            vals[k] = v;
        },
        insert: function(pos,k,v) {
            if (!Object.hasOwn(vals,k)) {
                keys.splice(pos,0,k);
                vals[k] = v;
            }
        },
        val: function(k) {return vals[k]},
        length: function(){return keys.length},
        keys: function(){return keys},
        values: function(){return vals}
    };
};

let myHash = makeOrderedHash();
```

Comment: You should use `Object.hasOwn(obj, k)` instead of `obj[k]`, so it works with falsy values as well.

Answer (score 22):

No, since the [Object type is specified to be an unordered collection of properties](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6), you can not rely on that. (Or: You can only rely on that an object is an unordered collection of properties.)

If you want to have an ordered hash set, you will need to implement it on your own.

Comment: Downvoting as this is answering only first part of question and doesn't attempt a solution

Comment: Downvoted because it's obvious the poster knew this.  Otherwise, he wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 5):

One trick I do is to store the data in a regular unordered hash, and then store the preferred order in an array. In JS, you can even make the order array part of the hash itself.

```
var myHash = {
  a: "2",
  b: "3",
  c: "1"
};

myHash.order = [ myHash.c, myHash.a, myHash.b ];

alert("I can access values by key. Here's B: " + myHash.b);
var message =  "I can access also loop over the values in order: ";

for (var i=0;i<myHash.order.length;i++)
{ 
  message = message + myHash.order[i] + ", ";
}

alert(message)
```

It's not exactly elegant, but it gets the job done.

Comment: This solution looks quite fragile to me, as the mechanism used for ordering is not encapsulated and the client code has to know about the internals to make it work... may be OK for throwaway projects, but certainly not production ready IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Realize its late but I needed this and couldn't find it elsewhere.
*UPDATE
Added necessary non-enumerable methods and properties.
Quick ES 5 implementation (polyfill as needed):

```
function orderedHash(object) {
    'use strict'
    var obj = object || {}
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        'length': {
            value: 0,
            writable: true
        },
        'keys' : {
            value: [],
            writable: true
        },
        'sortedBy': {
            value: '',
            writable: true
        }
    })
    this.hash(obj)
    obj = null
}
Object.defineProperties(orderedHash.prototype, {
    'sortByKeys': {
        value: function sortByKeys() {
            var i, len, name
            this.keys.sort(function(a, b) {   
                return a >= b ? 1 : -1
            })
            for (i=0, len = this.keys.length; i < len; ++i) {
                name = this.keys[i]
                this[i] = this[name]
            }
            this.sortedBy = 'keys'
            return null
        }   
    },
    'sortByValues': {
        value: function sortByValues() {
            var i, len, newIndex, name, ordered = [], names = this.keys.splice(0)
            this.keys = []
            for (i=0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
                ordered.push(this[i])
                ordered.sort(function(a, b) {   
                    return a >= b ? 1 : -1
                })
                newIndex = ordered.lastIndexOf(this[i])
                name = names[i]
                this.keys.splice(newIndex, 0 , name)
            }
            for (i=0, len = ordered.length; i < len; ++i) {
                this[i] = ordered[i]
            }
            this.sortedBy = 'values'
            return null
        }
    },
    'insert': {
        value: function insert(name, val) {
            this[this.length] = val
            this.length += 1
            this.keys.push(name)
            Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
                value: val,
                writable: true,
                configurable: true
            })
            if (this.sortedBy == 'keys') {
                this.sortByKeys()
            } else {
                this.sortByValues()
            }
            return null
        }
    },
    'remove': {
        value: function remove(name) {
            var keys, index, i, len
            delete this[name]
            index = this.keys[name]
            this.keys.splice(index, 1)
            keys = Object.keys(this)
            keys.sort(function(a, b) {   
                return a >= b ? 1 : -1
            })
            for (i=0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
                if (i >= index) {
                    this[i] = this[i + 1]
                }
            }
            delete this[this.length - 1]
            this.length -= 1
            return null
        }
    },
    'toString': {
        value: function toString() {
            var i, len, string = ""
            for (i=0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
                string += this.keys[i]
                string += ':'
                string += this[i].toString()
                if (!(i == len - 1)) {
                    string += ', '
                }
            }
            return string
        }
    },
    'toArray': {
        value: function toArray() {
            var i, len, arr = []
            for (i=0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
                arr.push(this[i])
            }
            return arr
        }
    },
    'getKeys': {
        value: function getKeys() {
            return this.keys.splice(0)
        }
    },
    'hash': {
        value: function hash(obj) {
            var i, len, keys, name, val
            keys = Object.keys(obj)
            for (i=0, len = keys.length; i < len; ++i) {
                name = keys[i]
                val = obj[name]
                this[this.length] = val
                this.length += 1
                this.keys.push(name)
                Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
                    value: val,
                    writable: true,
                    configurable: true
                })
            }
             if (this.sortedBy == 'keys') {
                this.sortByKeys()
            } else {
                this.sortByValues()
            }
            return null
        }
    }
})
```

What happens here is that by using `Object.defineProperty()` instead of assignment can we make the properties non-enumerable, so when we iterate over the hash using `for...in` or `Object.keys()` we only get the ordered values but if we check `hash.propertyname` it will be there. 
There are methods provided for insertion, removal, assimilating other objects (`hash()`), sorting by key, sorting by value, converting to array or string, getting the original index names, etc. I added them to the prototype but they are also non-enumerable, `for...in` loops still work.
I didn't take time to test it on non-primitives, but it works fine for strings, numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple way is to use an array to store the order.
You need to write a custom compare function to establish the order you require.
The down side is that you have to sort the array and keep track of relations, each time you change the hash table.

```
var order=[];
var hash={"h1":4,"h2":2,"h3":3,"h4":1};

function cmp(a,b) {
  if (hash[a] < hash[b]) return -1;
  if (hash[a] > hash[b]) return 1;
  return 0;
}

// Add initial hash object to order array
for(i in hash) order.push(i);
order.sort(cmp);
// h4:1 h2:2 h3:3 h1:4

// Add entry
hash['h5']=2.5;
order.push('h5');
order.sort(cmp);
// h4:1 h2:2 h5:2.5 h3:3 h1:4

// Delete entry
order.splice(order.indexOf('h5'), 1);
delete hash['h5'];
// h4:1 h2:2 h3:3 h1:4

// Display ordered hash array (with keys)
for(i in order) console.log(order[i],hash[order[i]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking @Craig_Walker solution, if you are only interested to know in which order the properties have been inserted, an easy solution would be :

```
var obj ={ }
var order = [];

function add(key, value) {
    obj[key] = value;
    order.push(key);
}

function getOldestKey() {
    var key = order.shift();
    return obj[key]
}

function getNewsetKey() {
    var key = order.pop();
    return obj[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use a native Map since it preserves the insertion order when looped over with `for in`

Comment: This duplicates [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41133779/735926) from 2016.

Answer (score 0):

```
class @OrderedHash

  constructor: (h_as_array=[])->
    @keys = []
    @vals = {}
    if h_as_array.length > 0
      i = 0
      while i < h_as_array.length
        @push(h_as_array[i], h_as_array[i+1])
        i += 2
    @

  push: (k,v)->
    @keys.push k if not @vals[k]
    @vals[k] = v

  length: ()-> return @keys.length
  keys:   ()-> return @keys
  val:   (k)-> return @vals[k]
  vals:   ()-> return @vals
  each: (callback)->
    return unless callback
    for k in @keys
      callback(@vals[k])
```