# Ordered Map Implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, underscore.js, ordered-map

**My Task**

In my JavaScript code i'm often using objects to "map" keys to values so i can later access them directly through a certain value. For example:

```
var helloMap = {};
helloMap.de = "Hallo";
helloMap["en"] = "Hello";
helloMap.es = "Hola";
```

So i build up the map object step by step in my source code using the two available notations *object style* and *array style*.

Later i can then access the values i added through `helloMap["de"]` for example. So thats all fine if i don't have to care about the order in which the attributes has been set on the object.

If i want to iterate the objects properties now as far as i know there is no way to ensure that i'll iterate them in the order they have been added (insertion order).

**Note:** I can't use some wrapper object and simply hold a array in there and then use its methods to add the values so something like this:

```
var HelloMap = function(){
  this.myMap = [];
  this.addProperty = function(key, value){
    this.myMap.push({key: key, value: value});
  }
}
```

or something similar won't work for me. So the solution needs to be absolutely transparent to the programmer using the object.

That said the object i needed would be an empty object which maintains the order of the properties that were added to it. Something like this would do:

```
var helloMap = {};
helloMap = getOrderAwareObject(helloMap);
```

so that every further assignment of the form `helloMap.xy = "foo"` and `helloMap["yz"] = "bar"` would be tracked in the object "in order",

**Possible Solutions**

Since i did not find any solution in underscore or jQuery giving me such a special object i came across the possibility of defining getters and setters for properties in JavaScript objects with `Object.defineProperty` since i can rely on *ECMAScript 5* standard i can use it.

The Problem with this one is, that you have to know all the possible properties that can be set on the object, before they are actually set. Since if you *define* it you got to *name* it.

What i am searching for is something like a **Default Getter** and **Default Setter** which applies on the object if no getter and setter has been defined for the property. So i could then hide the **sorted map** behind the object inteface.

- Is there already a solution for this in any framework you know?
- Is there a mechanism like "default getter/setter" ?

Comment: If order is important, then you have to use an Array.

Comment: Yea.. well.. thanks. But the problem with associative arrays is that they can't be accessed via the dot operator which i need. And by the way... are you sure that they even keep theire order?

Comment: Javascript doesn't do associative arrays. You can set Array properties, but they are independent of indexed Array items, and are orderless in the same way as properties of a plain js object.

Comment: Okay thanks so Arrays will be no solution here. At least in the "front" implementation. The object can keen an array in the back but that needs to be transparent on the object side.

Comment: If order is important, Array is the only solution. Yes, you can hide it inside a constructed object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a wrapper of some kind using an array internally, I'm afraid. ECMAScript 5 (which is the standard on which current browser JavaScript implementations are based) simply doesn't allow for ordered object properties.

However, ECMAScript 6 will have a [`Map` implementation](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-15.14) that has ordered properties. See also http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/10/09/ecmascript-6-collections-part-2-maps/.

There may also be other options in ECMAScript 6. See the following question:

[How can I define a default getter and setter using ECMAScript 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3112793/96100)

Comment: It isn't possible to prepend to a ES6 Map type right?

Answer (score 5):

Adding a link to a custom javascript library which provides Sorted maps and other implementation, for future reference in this thread . Check out https://github.com/monmohan/dsjslib
-msingh

Comment: This looks useful.  Thanks for posting.  I found this one as well (http://www.collectionsjs.com/sorted-map) but the documentation is not clear, the API is confusing (eg set(key, value) vs add(value, key)) and as a result, I'm having difficulty trusting the implementation

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a general solution but non-general solutions are very simple to construct.

Typically, you maintain an Array of objects, with several methods defined as properties of the Array. At least, that's my approach.

Here's an example, taken (in a modified form) from a larger application :

```
var srcs = [];
srcs.find = function(dist) {
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        if(dist <= this[i].dist) { return this[i]; }
    }
    return null;
};
srcs.add = function(dist, src) {
    this.push({ dist:dist, src:src });
}
srcs.remove = function(dist) {
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i].dist === dist) {
            srcs.splice(i,1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
srcs.add(-1, 'item_0.gif' );
srcs.add(1.7, 'item_1.gif');
srcs.add(5, 'item_2.gif');
srcs.add(15, 'item_3.gif');
srcs.add(90, 'item_4.gif');
```

Unfortunately, you lose the simplicity of a plain js object lookup, but that's the price you pay for having an ordered entity.

If you absolutely must have order and dot.notation, then maintain a plain js Object for lookup *and* an Array for order. With care, the two can be maintained with total integrity.

Comment: Thanks for the last hint here! Maintaining both an object and an array seems to be a good "for now" solution for my concrete case.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798893/ordered-hash-in-javascript) question. I implemented an basic ordered hashtable (ES 5+ only, didn't bother to polyfill)

Answer (score -1):

```
var put = function(k,v){
 if(map[k]){
   console.log("Key "+ k+" is already present");
 }else
 {
   var newMap = {};
   map[k] = v;
   Object.keys(map).sort().forEach(function(key){
   newMap[key] = map[key];
 });
   map = newMap;
   //delete newMap; in case object memory need to release
   return map;
 }
}
```

Put method will always take a key-value pair, internally creates another map with sorted keys from the actual map, update the value and return the updated map with sorted keys.No external library need to includ.