# get particular elements from an associate array / object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in JavaScript like this

```
var arr = [];
arr['5u'] = 250;
arr['1u'] = 120;
arr['7u'] = 670;
arr['2u'] = 210; //<-----
arr['9u'] = 850; //<-----
arr['8u'] = 129; //<-----
arr['3u'] = 382;
arr['6u'] = 391;
arr['4u'] = 432;
```

I want to get only 3 elements starting from index of 3 to 5 in above array. How can I get so? the result should be something like this.

```
[210,850,129];
```

I tried accessing it as **arr[3]** and off-course as it should it is showing *undefined*. Now how can I get so?

I want to access values with loop like this

```
for(var i=3; i<6; i++)
{
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: You are just adding property the the array object but not putting elements in the array. When you need a hash structure, use object `{}` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Well I thought so but then I would not be able to sort it

Comment: You can't sort it too. `arr.sort(function(a, b) {return b - a});` will just return an empty array.

Comment: Well if so then what would be the idea to solve it?

Comment: You can't rely on sorting by object keys.

Comment: I have to sort by values not by keys

Comment: for the time being if we ignore sorting case what would be the rest to do?

Comment: So you know what values you need?

Comment: I have updated my question, now that should make better sense

Comment: Then better you suggest the one that is good

Comment: It is just a simple array which is populated dynamically with keys having string indices

Comment: Use "standard" array or it's a constraint using numeric index or a requirement to use string indexes ?

Comment: Do you need to keep the string indices? If you won't use them in your code, you can just reformat them as regular arrays and access them using the indices that you want, check your code and make sure you need them, otherwise, any of the answers we provide will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use this technique

```
arr[0] = [250, '5u'];
arr[1] = [120, '1u'];
arr[2] = [670, '7u'];
arr[3] = [210, '2u'];
arr[4] = [850, '9u'];
arr[5] = [129, '8u'];
arr[6] = [391, '3u'];
arr[7] = [432, '6u'];
```

now you can sort like this

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {return b[0] - a[0]});
```

and access any element like this

```
console.log(arr[3][0]);
console.log(arr[4][0]);
console.log(arr[5][0]);
```

Comment: This looks promising. Let me try it please

Comment: @CodeDevil Out of curiosity, what's different about this answer compared to mine?

Comment: @Jack in first I just liked this answer and it was just exactly what I wanted but when you asked about the difference between yours and this. I thought that this is simple and working great but then I made few benchmarks and this answer is much faster than yours. You can try it yourself with loop of 1000000. This answer is taking approx. 4 seconds to sort array and yours is taking about 10 seconds.

Comment: @CodeDevil I don't see how that's possible by just having the values reversed inside each element? Do you have a benchmark on jsperf.com?

Comment: Hold on I just removed. Let me make again. I really appreciate what you suggest. Wait please

Answer (score 1):

Since you have provided keys for the array, you need to access using `arr['2u']`, `arr['9u']` and `arr['8u']`. You can't access using arr[3] as it is not stored with those indices.

Comment: It is not sure what would be index since array would be sorted. Means I am not sure what will be either 9u, 8u or so. I just know that I want to get so and so index numbered element

Comment: What does means that you know what you want to get?... like from fourth element to the sixth?, i think you should explain better, since anirudh answer is just what you asked, try reformulating

Comment: Are you sorting based on the indices or the values of the array?

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely safe, you're going to need parallel data structures.  What you're describing is a map not an array.  The problem is a map is unordered so you can't rely on the order of the elements you put in it.  You're going to need an accompanying array to keep track of the order.  See this: [Ordered hash in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798893/ordered-hash-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I would populate the array in this manner:

```
var arr = [], 
map = {},
append = function(key, value) {
    return arr[map[key] = arr.length] = [key, value];
}

append('5u', 250);
append('1u', 120);
append('7u', 670);
append('2u', 210); //<-----
append('9u', 850); //<-----
append('8u', 129); //<-----
append('3u', 382);
append('6u', 391);
append('4u', 432);
```

*The `map` structure allows you to find an element by its identifier.*

In this way, you can use `arr.slice()`:

```
arr.slice(3, 6); // [['2u', 210], ['9u', 850], ['8u', 129]]
```

Sorting this will maintain the key - value pairs as well:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1]; // or reversed, whatever
});
```

Note that after a sort you will have to rebuild the map; that's if you would actually that structure.

Answer (score 1):

**YOU CAN CREATE YOUR OWN PROTOTYPE FUNCTION FOR ARRAY LIKE THIS BELOW,**

```
Array.prototype.selectIndex = function (n) {
          var count = 0;
          for (var i in arr) {
              if (count == n) val = arr[i];
              count++;
          }
          console.log(val);
      };
```

and you can simply enter the index number like this below,

```
arr.selectIndex(3);
arr.selectIndex(4);
arr.selectIndex(5);
```

**SEE THIS [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/laxuwewo/2/edit)**

Comment: Properties in an object don't necessarily have a fixed ordering.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this way also

var arr = {};    
arr[0] = {'key':'5u','val':250};
arr[1] = {'key':'1u','val':120};
arr[2] = {'key':'7u','val':670};
arr[3] ={'key':'2u','val':210}; //<-----
arr[4] ={'key':'9u','val':850}; //<-----
arr[5] ={'key':'8u','val':129}; //<-----
arr[6] ={'key':'3u','val':382};
arr[7] = {'key':'6u','val':391};
arr[8] ={'key':'4u','val':432};
console.log(arr[3]['val']);
console.log(arr[4]['val']);
console.log(arr[5]['val']);
```

Comment: If you're using objects it would be better to use `{key: '5u', value: 250}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 var arr = [], arr2 = [];
    arr['5u'] = 250;
    arr['1u'] = 120;
    arr['7u'] = 670;
    arr['2u'] = 210; //<-----
    arr['9u'] = 850; //<-----
    arr['8u'] = 129; //<-----
    arr['3u'] = 382;
    arr['6u'] = 391;
    arr['4u'] = 432;
    var count = 0;
    for(var i in arr){

        if(count == 3 || count == 4 || count == 5)
            arr2.push(arr[i]);
     count++;
    }

    console.log(arr2)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5n8Zn/)

Comment: Your answer is good but isn't there any way to access it directly with index because this way we have to loop from start everytime it is called. I will not be that good if the array has about 100000 values to handle and accessing only last 3 elements

Comment: @Girish Lol, almost same approach that mine. What if you want the index you can store the i value in the second array, then you can use the keys to access the main array, but i see no point, at least in what you showed us.

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = arr.length;
var data=new array();
var i=0;
while (len--){
    if(i==3) {
        data[i-3]=arr[i];
    }    
    i++;
    if(i==5){
        break;
    }
}
```

now, your data array will contain desired values