# What is the best way to sort array of objects by sub-value?

Tags: node.js, arrays, sorting

Lets say I have an object:

```
    var testobject = { 
      '1100': {
        name: 'Jane',
        status: '3'
      },
      '2000': {
        name: 'Jack',
        status: '1'
      },
      '1000': {
        name: 'Jason',
        status: '5'
      }
    };
```

What is the best way to sort it by 'status' value?
To get order like this:

```
    { 
      '2000': {
        name: 'Jack',
        status: '1'
      },
      '1100': {
        name: 'Jane',
        status: '3'
      },
      '1000': {
        name: 'Jason',
        status: '5'
      }
    };
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: objects aren't sorted, you could use a map see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41133779/3462319)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, maps are exactly what I was looking for.