# array in javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

i have a piece of code like below

```
var abc = 
{
2: {label: "raju"},
10: {label: "samu"},
3:  {label: "sidh"}, 
1:  {label: "kat"}, 

};

for(var i in abc){ alert(i); }
```

in mozilla fire fox it alerts 2,10,3,1. but in chrome it shows 1,2,3,10

but my requirement is the first one (as shown in fire fox)
what to do for getting the same result in chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elements order - for (... in ...) loop in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-for-in-loop-in-javascript)

Comment: `for(var i in abc)` is not what you think it is (an array element iterator). If you use a normal indexed for loop, and a normal array, surprises you will not get.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which the "for(var i in ...)" retrieves the items is not defined. For an array-like behaviour you have to use an array ;)

```
var abc = [
  { nr: 2, label: "raju" },
  { nr: 10, label: "samu" },
  { nr: 3, label: "sidh" },
  { nr: 1, label: "kat" }
];

for (var i = 0, length = abc.length; i < length; i++)
   alert(abc[i].nr);
```

Comment: A `hasOwnProperty` check is usually a good idea in a `for...in` loop: `if (abc.hasOwnProperty(i)) {...}`