# Finding objects in JS array and storing names to new array?

Tags: javascript

So, I have an array that contains X objects, all named by dates and containing useless data beyond their name.
I want to store these dates in an array for later use and objects are, apparently, not found in an array by array[i], so how do I iterate through the array and just save the names to a string in another array?

Edit: Ok this question was due to a major brainfart... The obvious answer would be

```
    var dP = $('#calendar').GetDate();
    var dPTmp = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (var id in dP) {
        dPTmp[i] = dP[id].toString();
        i++;
    }
    console.log(dPTmp);
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing, since you are interchanging `Array` with `Object`. In JavaScript, there is nothing like an associative array. Those are objects. Can you clearify this?

Comment: var dP = $('#calendar').GetDates();  --- dP will now be an array of objects named "October 18 2010 00:00" that contains lists of days of the week, the months of the year and whatnot, which I don't need. I need the name as a string.

Comment: Make sure to check `.hasOwnProperty()` in the loop! You will get in serious trouble otherwise.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks for the reminder! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As elusive stated in comments, you're not dealing with an `Array` but with an `Object`.

However, the construct you're probably looking for is the [`for..in` statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) that lets you loop through the object's properties.

Something along these lines:

```
var object1 = { '2010-10-18': 'today', '2010-10-19': 'tomorrow' },
    dateArray = [],
    dateStr = '';

for (dateStr in object1) {
    // here you should probably check that dateStr
    // and the corresponding value are in correct format
    // in case someone or something has extended the Object class
    dateArray.push(dateStr)
}

// dateArray is now [ '2010-10-18', '2010-10-19' ]
```

Also note that you can't trust that the object's properties will be iterated "in order". See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-for-in-loop-in-javascript).