# How do I know when the last asynchronous function has returned results in the "for key in ob" loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have the following code to go through an obj:

```
var data = [];
var obj = {...
};

for (var key in obj) {
  if (!obj[key]["something"]) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': key
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

         data.push({...});

      }
    });

    // if last item
    $.post("...", data, ...);
  }
}
```

Now I want to post all the data retrieved by running all asynchronous functions called in the loop.

Comment: You can just run it after the for loop.. it's the same.. right?

Comment: You'll have to show us the asynchronous function, and what it returns etc. as well.

Comment: One way would be to return a promise object from each function and run `$.when([promises]).then(...)` after the loop.

Comment: That last function, must wait to the async function to end or not?

Comment: Look at the correct answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076732/how-to-get-the-last-item-in-a-javascript-value-object-with-a-for-loop    You should not use `for(var key in obj)`

Comment: @Sergeon, Correct. I need to wait until all the data is returned and write the info to the database only once.

Comment: Assuming your asynchronous function returns a `Promise`, you can use `Promise.all`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `geocoder.geocode()` (that is part of Google Maps API) doesn't return either a `Promise` or a `Deferred`, you'll have to encapsulate the request in your own `Promise`, then use `Promise.all()`:

```
var promises = [];

for (var key in obj) {
    if (!obj[key]["something"]) {
        promises.push(new Promise(function (resolveWith, rejectWith) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': key
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    data.push(...);
                    resolveWith(results);
                } else
                    rejectWith(results);
            });
        }));
    }
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function (resultsArr) {
    // at this point all requests have been fulfilled
    $.post(...);
});
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: This looks like what I need indeed! Will get back shortly to tell if it's worked.

Comment: Although getting the following error when the obj has many keys: Uncaught (in promise) null > .. url .. . It works with a single key for some reason.

Comment: @Deka87, If you're going to iterate on the keys of `obj`, you'll need `for (var key in Object.keys(obj)) { ... }`

Comment: Had to move the promises.push() part inside the status === ok block, because otherwise once it had a single reject it didn't post data to the database at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery.Deferred()

```
var obj = {...};
var deferred = $.Deferred();
deferred.done(function(){ /*.. asynchronous function here ..*/ });

for (var key in obj) {
  if (!obj[key]["something"]) {
    deferred.resolve();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know which key is last, but as there are no determinate order to hashed keys in an object it will most likely not turn out the way you want in edge cases.

One way to at least get some kind of last key would be to iterate once before the main loop, like this:

```
var obj = {...
};

var lastkey;

for (var key in obj) {
  lastkey = key;
}

for (var key in obj) {
  if( key === lastkey) {
    ... do lastkey stuff instead here
  } else {
    if (!obj[key]["something"]) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': key
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       ...
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

If the 'obj' does not change during or between those 2 loops the last key should turn out the same in both loops.

Comment: Property order is not guaranteed to be the same between iterations, though in practice it may be.

Comment: I just thought that getting to the last key of the obj doesn't mean the the last asynchronous function has finished getting the data..

Comment: @Deka87 , it will most likely get to the last key of the object long before those asynchronous calls are done. You maybe should ask about how to add a call after all the other calls, and not ask how to get the last key. It will give you better answers.

Comment: @Huggabear, you are right. Updated the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var data = [];
 var obj = {...
 };

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
 var last = keys[keys.length-1];

for (var key in obj) {
if (!obj[key]["something"]) {
geocoder.geocode({
  'address': key
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

     data.push({...});

  }
});

// if last item
if (key == last)
$.post("...", data, ...);
 } 
 }
```